# Is it possible to set a timeout for LinkWrite[]?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

This came up in relation to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/708/12)

Is it possible to set a timeout for `LinkWrite`?  `LinkWrite` seems to block until the sent data is read on the other end of the link.  Can it block indefinitely or does it have a long timeout?  If it doesn't have a default timeout, is it possible to set one?

#### An example

Let's create two new kernels in the front end (this might overwrite your existing kernels, but it will be reversed after restarting the front end):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 EvaluatorNames -> {"Local" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> True}, 
   "K1" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
   "K2" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}}]
```

Then open two new notebooks, and in the first one evaluate

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator -> "K2"]

link = LinkCreate["alink"]

LinkWrite[link, "boo"]
```

In the second one evaluate

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator -> "K1"]

link = LinkConnect["alink"]

LinkRead[link]
```

`LinkWrite` in the first one will only return after `LinkRead` has finished evaluating in the second one.

---

If the answer is that it's not possible to set a timeout, that can be reasonable too.  I was wondering about this:  suppose we're running a long parallel calculation, and we interrupt the main kernel to enter a subsession and inspect the state (`Evaluation -> Interrupt -> Enter subsession`).  Is it possible that one of the parallel kernels will time out while trying to send the result, and the calculation won't be able to resume after returning from the subsession?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the LinkWrite in a TimeConstrained call?

Comment: To address the last part of your question separately--yes, it probably will time out; the timeout period is set by ``Parallel`Settings`$MathLinkTimeout`` and has a default value of 15 seconds. May I also suggest that you consider changing the title of this question, given that `LinkWrite` is non-blocking on a properly initialized MathLink connection? (To flush the message queues, one would use `LinkFlush`, which *is* blocking until the messages have been sent.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. I have seen the 15 timeout when parallel kernels fail to launch.  But in a quick test, if they *do* launch correctly, they don't seem to be affected, no matter how long I keep the master kernel paused in a `Dialog[]`.  I still don't feel confident enough about this interrupting a *long* calculation and going into a dialog, but at least in those simple tests I did it seemed to work without issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting up MathLink connections between kernels acting as peers (as opposed to in a master-slave arrangement) is sparsely documented, and the critical function you need to make this work, i.e. `LinkActivate`, is undocumented altogether (although, if you clear its `ReadProtected` attribute, you will see that it is merely a synonym for `LinkConnect`, which itself is a version of `LinkOpen`). In fact, `LinkRead` and `LinkWrite` both work with message queues and are not inherently blocking operations, but the behaviour you see is the result of the MathLink connection not having been initialized properly before writing.

To initialize the connection correctly, modify your code as follows:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator -> "K2"]

link = LinkCreate["alink"]

(* Evaluate only after calling LinkConnect/LinkActivate from K1 *)
LinkActivate[link]

(* No longer blocks *)
LinkWrite[link, "boo"]
```

and

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator -> "K1"]

(* Evaluate immediately after calling LinkCreate from K2. *)
link = LinkConnect["alink"];
LinkActivate[link] (* this call is blocking! *)

LinkRead[link]
```

Why this is undocumented I do not know; to my knowledge the only place where this is described is the (rather specialist) book, *MathLink: Network Programming with Mathematica* by Chikara Miyaji and Paul Abbott. I discovered it when I was curious as to whether it was possible to write an MPI-style message-passing implementation in pure *Mathematica*. (The answer is yes; I posted some code on MathGroup [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jun/msg00535.html) if you are interested.)

Comment: So after creating the link, I need to connect from *both* sides.  You explanation makes it much more clear how these work.

Comment: It seems that `LinkActivate` is not just a synonym of `LinkConnect` for *any* argument type.  If I try to use only `LinkConnect` in its place, this example won't work.  Got to get some sleep, will play more tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't tried that so not sure. Also, note that although some operations seem to work without it, if you don't call `LinkActivate`/`LinkConnect` after setting up a peer-to-peer link, you'll usually find that `LinkReadyQ` gives incorrect results. Obviously this is a problem if you want to avoid blocking.

Comment: @OleksandrR. `LinkReadyQ` isn't returning incorrect results.  It has a different meaning for unconnected links.  `LinkReadyQ` for an unconnected link tells you whether the other side of the link exists and is ready to be connected. E.g., if you've opened a listening link, there's no guarantee that the other side exists, and polling it with `LinkReadyQ` may be useful to determine whether calling `LinkActivate` (or `LinkConnect` with a `LinkObject` argument) could hang indefinitely.  That's still technically possible, of course, if the other side doesn't connect the link, but less likely.

Comment: @JohnFultz thanks, that's very useful information. Am I right in thinking that this behaviour is undocumented? At least, I don't see any mention of this on the pages for either `LinkReadyQ` or `MLReady()`. Actually, my presumption it was a bug was prompted by apparently buggy behaviour of `MLReadyParallel()` (which, however, seems to work correctly now). Am I right that `MLReadyParallel()` received a fix in version 8.0.4 or thereabouts?

Comment: @OleksandrR. yes, you're probably right that it's not documented...but I doubt it will ever change, as these behaviors are well-known within WRI and probably frequently relied upon. For example, the FE relies upon this behavior of `MLReady()`. I don't know whether `MLReadyParallel()` has the same behavior or not. The FE uses `MLReadyParallel()` extensively (well, only in one place, but that place is executed all the time), but only with links that are already connected. I'm not aware of any significant and recent bug fixes to it.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the `LinkWrite` in `TimeConstrained` as:

```
TimeConstrained[LinkWrite[link, "boo"], t]
```

where `t` is the number of seconds you'd like to wait before it times out. You can also add a default command to evaluate if it fails, using the third argument.

```
TimeConstrained[LinkWrite[link, "boo"], t, Print["Timed out."]]
```