# How can I access a variable in one evaluator from another evaluator?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, notebooks, kernel

I have two notebooks, each with a different kernel. Is there a way to grab the value of a variable in KernelA from KernelB?

Comment: You could try assigning the variable to a tagging rule and accessing via `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,{TaggingRules, ...}]`

Comment: You could use a file.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch interesting approach, an you give all the code for your example as a solution?

Comment: IMO probably the best way is using MathLink (Mike's suggestion of course uses it indirectly). I showed how you can link up two kernels [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/is-it-possible-to-set-a-timeout-for-linkwrite/1059#1059)--you may be interested in the linked MathGroup posting too. An updated version of that code is [here](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/8QKEHQP/0/blob?download).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Could you update your answer with the latest version of the code? (you can perhaps use belisarius' notebook-in-image palette to upload it if it is long)

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yeah, sure that would be a fine place. Do you have an account? If so, I can add you to the repo. If not, I'll upload it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this out:

Lets say you have a variable called `kernelA` in one notebook using Kernel A. Then:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "KernelA"}] = kernelA
```

In your other notebook, running Kernel B just evaluate

```
variableFromOthernotebook = CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "KernelA"}]
```

**Edit**

An alternative that might be faster (almost certainly would be if a lot of `TaggingRules` are used).

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, TaggingRules -> {"KernelA" -> kernelA}]
```

than in the other notebook:

```
variableFromOthernotebook = "KernelA" /. 
(TaggingRules /. Options[$FrontEndSession, TaggingRules])
```

Comment: There is significant lag in this example :(

Comment: @M.R. can you explain what you mean? A lag setting the value? A lag obtaining the value?

Comment: @MikeH. I find your method surprisingly performant, with no obvious lag, as well as ingenious in its simplicity. A lot of optimization must go in to the front-end link, as its bandwidth for large transfers is actually higher than the approach I demonstrate (although it has a marginally higher latency). As usual, though, older versions win out in the performance stakes: using my example, *Mathematica* 5.2 is about twice as fast as version 8 for basic MathLink transfers...

Comment: @OleksandrR. In the past I have found that if you have to set a large number of rules (from memory 30-50), `TaggingRules` can slow down quite a bit but for a small number I have found it to be fairly efficient. Why is V5.2 faster than V8 for MathLink transfers?

Comment: @MikeH. I don't really know why, but it seems with each new version, along with many new features, more overhead gets added to the fundamental operations. In this case it's probably a question of MathLink interface version 2 vs. 3, the latter being slower for some reason. Basic manipulation of `DownValues` is also about a third faster in 5.2 than 8.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch By lag I mean, that if you change the value dynamically in one notebook, the other lags behind: Slider[Dynamic[
  CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "Alpha"}]], {0, 100}]

Comment: @M.R. Your question merely asks how to grab a variable from one kernel in another: no mention of dynamics and sliders or ultimate intended usage. If the answer disappoints isn't it fair to say that the question has insufficient information?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch It's a great answer. I should have asked "How can I (dynamically and/or most quickly) access a variable in one evaluator from another evaluator?"

Comment: @M.R. I have found `TaggingRules` to be slow if you have to use `CurrentValue` when there are a lot of tagging rules defined. In those cases I have found it more efficient to use `SetOptions.` You might want to try that and see if it helps. See edit.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a very simple example of how to use MathLink for this sort of communication. I will use normal code blocks for kernel A and quoted code blocks for kernel B. You must evaluate these in the order shown.

```
link = LinkCreate["a uniquely named link"];
```

> ```
> link = LinkConnect["a uniquely named link"];
> LinkActivate[link];
> MathLink`AddSharingLink[link];
> ```

```
LinkActivate[link];
SetAttributes[remoteEvaluate, HoldAllComplete];
remoteEvaluate[expr_] := (
  LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[expr]]; LinkFlush[link];
  First@Cases[
    While[Sow[#, Head[#]] &[LinkRead[link]]; LinkReadyQ[link]] ~Reap~ ReturnPacket,
    ReturnPacket[result_] :> result, {3}
   ]
 );
```

The idea is that the result of evaluating `expr` on kernel B comes back to kernel A as the body of a `ReturnPacket`. Other types of packets may also be produced (for example, `ExpressionPacket`s are generated when something is `Print`ed), but we ignore these for present purposes.

Now:

> ```
> var = Range[5];
> ```

```
var
(* -> var *)

remoteEvaluate[var]
(* -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

If we care to check, we will also find that `var` did not suffer the indignity of unpacking and was quite unmolested in general by this process.

One important point to note is that it is not legal to call `` MathLink`AddSharingLink `` on the same link from two different kernels, as this causes a deadlock. Therefore, if you want to share data in a symmetric fasion, you will have to set up a link from A to B *and* another link from B to A. Although links are in fact bidirectional, this sort of communication requires matching reads and writes to be placed on the link in the appropriate sequence. Unless A and B are both being controlled by C, it will be easier in many cases to defer to the main loop as shown above, because although it renders each link effectively unidirectional, it also enables single-ended communication.

Comment: I didn't manage to get this working in 9, take a look [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9436355#9436355)

Comment: This this works on 11.2 (osx)