# Assign keyboard shortcut unique to notebook

Tags: version-10

What is the most portable way to assign keyboard shortcuts unique to each notebook?

To clarify I would like to have the keyboard shortcut change when simply changing the current `InputNotebook`.

Currently I'm have the following code which allows for me to essentially have the defined function be defined in a notebook and execute in the Global` context.

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "DuplicatePreviousOutput", {MenuItem["Ctrl &q", 
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute@ToExpression@MakeBoxes[
       F2[]
       ], MenuKey["q", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]
```

I would like to somehow attach functions to notebooks without changing the context(most ideal).  Alternatively I might be able to use something like a custom `FrontEnd'NotebookExecute` instead of `FrontEnd'KernelExecute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advantage of Mike question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/how-can-i-access-a-variable-in-one-evaluator-from-another-evaluator/14168#14168).

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "DuplicatePreviousOutput", {MenuItem["Ctrl &F2", 
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute@ToExpression@MakeBoxes[

       CurrentValue[
          InputNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "keyShortcuts", "F2"}][];

       ], MenuKey["F2", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]
```