# Can output of one kernel be called from another on the same PC?

Tags: front-end

I have two instances of Mathematica running on the same PC. Can I call the output of one from the other?

For example if Out[100] is on kernel1 how do I refer to it on kernel2?

Comment: Maybe naming your evaluator? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluator.html

Comment: Is this a solution for you? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/how-can-i-access-a-variable-in-one-evaluator-from-another-evaluator/14168#14168

Comment: This is the cleanest and most robust solution I can think of: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14176/38205

Comment: Do you mean two Mathematica instances or two different kernels under the same FE/Mathematica?

Comment: @Kuba If I have two open notebooks how do I tell if they are from two kernels  or two instances of Mathematica? If I try to open another Mathematica it asks for a license. So  my guess is that mine are two kernels.

Comment: @Maesumi You can tell by the parent process. And since you opened them you can tell because you know anyway. Don't get me wrong, wording you have used suggests something else that you 'guess', which is way more difficult to solve so that information matters. If you opened two notebooks in MMA and set separate kernels for them, just say so instead of 'two instances'.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**

*(comparison to other answers)*

This answer doesn't require the remote kernel to do anything, in contrast I believe to the linked answers as well as @b3m2a1's answer. For example, if the remote kernel is computing something, it will not be able to send results to the inspecting kernel.

*(multiple Mathematica sessions)*

If you indeed have multiple Mathematica sessions, then the Front End will not have access to both kernels. In this case you may use the Channel or Socket frameworks to communicate between the kernels, but I won't bother with this unless the question is clarified.

*(improved answer)*

Also, I cleaned up the function a bit, so that it is simpler, and so that it can work with arbitrary expressions (not just [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out)).

```
SetAttributes[RemoteValue, HoldFirst]
RemoteValue[expr_, kernel_] := Uncompress @ First @ FrontEndExecute @ ExportPacket[
    BoxData @ DynamicBox[Compress @ expr, Evaluator->kernel],
    "PlainText"
]
```

And, the same example as before:

```
RemoteValue[Out[28], "Local 2"]
% + 1
```

> 1596
>
> 1597

**Original answer**

There is probably a much simpler method, but here is one possibility:

```
RemoteValue[line_, kernel_] := Uncompress @ First @ FrontEndExecute @ ExportPacket[
    Cell[
        BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Dynamic[Compress @ Out[line], Evaluator -> kernel],
        "Output"
    ],
    "PlainText"
]
```

It's hard to simulate multiple kernels in an answer, but this is what I get when I use the above:

```
RemoteValue[28, "Local 2"]
% + 1
```

> 1596
>
> 1597

where the input in the "Local 2" kernel was `798 2`, and the second line shows that the actual value is available.

Another possibility if you just want to see the output is to use [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic):

```
r = Dynamic[Out[28], Evaluator->"Local 2"]
```

> 1596

but in this case the actual value is not available:

```
Head @ r
```

> Dynamic

Comment: Clever to use the boxes as a transfer protocol. There ought to be a way to make a single call into something like ``MathLink`CallFrontEndHeld[FrontEnd`Value["expr"]]`` I feel and specify the `Evaluator`...

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

Here's how we'd do this for your case specifically. Assuming we created and connected a tunnel called `"shuttle"`. First we do this on kernel 1:

```
TunnelWrite["shuttle", Evaluate@Out[32]]
```

And then on kernel 2:

```
TunnelRead["shuttle", Hold]

{Hold[{1, 2, 3, 9}]}
```

The hold is optional. I just added it for flavor.

#### Original

Here's another option that works directly at the MathLink level and so has more efficient data transport.

I wrote a layer or five on top of [`LinkCreate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinkCreate.html) and friends to help ease some of the dangers and difficulties of using [`Links`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinkObject.html) for inter-kernel communication.

The package is called [KernelTunnels](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/KernelTunnels.wl). Here's an example:

[image: tunneling]

We can see I create a tunnel with `TunnelCreate` in the first kernel (just a link+metadata) called `"shuttle"`. The tunnel data is written to a temporary .mx file so as to allow good unified interprocess communication.

In the second kernel I then connect to the same tunnel with `TunnelConnect`. At this point the two are attached to each other and can communicate freely.

`TunnelWrite` will write to the `LinkObject` and `TunnelRead` will drain everything off the link, wrapping it in the head passed as the second argument first. Note that `TunnelWrite` writes the unevaluated expression by default, so you'll need to use `Evaluate` if you want to circumvent this behavior.

There's also some stuff in there for adding handlers for `TunnelRead` (it can be different on both ends).

If this is useful I can properly document the API, but these functions are the heart of it.

Comment: Doesn't OP mean two MMAs as opposed to two kernels under the same FE?

Comment: Unclear...that case is just fundamentally impossible without dumping to disk, though, I think. Although `LinkConnect` might work just without the shared memory argument.