# Multiplayer game in Mathematica: how to communicate between kernels?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

This may have been asked already, but I am considering making a game in Mathematica that two people can play. However, the issue with my idea is that the other player can't view the cards of the first player. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I would tackle this problem? I would use two different computers, both with Mathematica installed.

Comment: this is far too vague. How are they communicating in the first place?

Comment: That is my question. Is there any system in Mathematica that would allow two notebooks to communicate? @george2079

Comment: @indiaash524 I've never used it, but you can read about `MathLink` in the docs and see if that's what you're looking for. Especially there is an article in the docs named "Using Mathlink to communicate between Mathematica sessions"

Comment: An example using MathLink is provided [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/216742) for two Raspberry Pis.  I think this question is interesting but too broad at the moment.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*MathLink* can be used to establish communication between two kernels on different machines using TCP/IP.

A [basic example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingMathLinkToCommunicateBetweenMathematicaSessions.html) that illustrates the technique can be found in the *Mathematica* documentation.

The basic sequence of events is like this:

1. The server creates an endpoint using [LinkCreate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinkCreate.html).
2. The client connects using [LinkConnect](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinkConnect.html).
3. When one side wants to send a message to the other, it uses [LinkWrite](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinkWrite.html).
4. Each side periodically polls to see whether the other has sent a message using [LinkReadyQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinkReadyQ.html).  If it returns `True`, then the message can be read using [LinkRead](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinkRead.html).

There are some gotchas to be aware of:

- A client should write a message to the server immediately after connecting.  This establishes the actual connection.  Also, I have experienced erratic behaviour from `LinkConnectedQ` and `LinkReadyQ` until that first message arrives at the server.  **UPDATE** @OleksandrR. points out that the undocumented function `LinkActivate` will correct this issue.  See his discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1059/142).
- On principle, I recommend reading incoming messages in held form using `LinkRead[..., HoldComplete]` and interpreting them using purpose-built code.  If you simply evaluate the messages directly, it opens a window for a prankster (or worse) to execute arbitrary code on your machine.
- During the initial debugging stage, it is easy for communicating programs to get out of synch with one another, resulting in hangs.  Sometimes the kernel resists aborting or interrupting expressions when engaged in blocking I/O.  I have found it useful to create buttons somewhere in a notebook that will close or interrupt the active link when pressed.  The button actions run with a separate kernel link and can sometimes be helpful to forcibly terminate a cranky connection.
- The link connection name needs to be communicated from the server to the client by some out-of-band means (e.g. the server player must tell/text/IM/email his chosen IP address and port to the client player).

The following (v9) code implements a toy one-line chat application for a client/server pair.  First, a function to create the chat panel used by both sides:

```
chat[link_] :=
  DynamicModule[{button, tick=0, valid=True, ready, connected, in="", out=""}
  , button = Function[, Button[##, Enabled -> Dynamic[valid]], HoldAll]
  ; DynamicWrapper[
      Grid[
        { {"Link name:", Dynamic@If[valid, link[[1]], "Closed"]}
        , {"Tick:", Dynamic@tick}
        , {"Message:", Dynamic[in]}
        , {button["Send", LinkWrite[link, out]; out=""], InputField[Dynamic@out, String]}
        , {button["Close", LinkClose[link]]}
        }
      ]
    , Refresh[
        tick += 1
      ; {valid, connected, ready} =
          Quiet @ Check[
            {True, LinkConnectedQ @ link, LinkReadyQ @ link}
          , {False, False, False}
          ]
      ; If[ready, in = LinkRead[link]]
      , If[valid, UpdateInterval -> 0, None]
      , TrackedSymbols :> {}
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Next, a function to create a server-side chat panel that listens on a specified IP port:

```
chatServer[port_] :=
  chat @ LinkCreate[ToString@port, LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
```

Finally, a function to create a client-side chat panel using the link name shown on the server's panel:

```
chatClient[linkName_] :=
  Module[{link = LinkConnect[linkName, LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]}
  , LinkActivate[link]
  ; chat[link]
  ]
```

The server creates his panel...

[image: server panel screenshot]

... then communicates the link name to the client by some means.  Only the first part of the name needs to be communicated, `8000@192.168.1.2` in the example.  The client then uses this name to create his panel:

[image: client panel screenshot]

The two can then communicate until one of them presses the *Close* button.

The *Tick* field in this example simulates the background work performed by the game while waiting for communication from its peer.  The code polls for messages as fast as possible, but this rate can be throttled by adjusting the `UpdateInterval` option to `Refresh` in `chat`.

As is customary in these toy examples, little attempt is made to recover from error conditions.

Comment: Regarding some of your "gotchas": I ran into these myself and discussed it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/is-it-possible-to-set-a-timeout-for-linkwrite/1059#1059). John Fultz mentioned in response that the meaning of `LinkConnectedQ`/`LinkReadyQ` simply differs for the unconnected link--it tells you whether it is safe to try writing to the link or calling `LinkActivate` on it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for that very useful information.  I have updated my answer to incorporate it.

Comment: Should the *server side* be *client side* in the line right above `chatClient[..]:=`? btw +1, very concise guide.

Comment: @Silvia Yes, corrected.  Thanks.

Comment: It just works in LAN...

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to the new `Channel` functionality in *Mathematica* 11, it is now easy to make (basic) multiplayer games with *Mathematica*!

To demonstrate, I'll modify my hex game from [The Game of Hex in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125475/731). Start by copying all that code into a notebook and evaluate it. Then evaluate the following code:

```
boardClicked[{i_, j_}] := If[
  board[[i, j]] == 0 && currentPlayer == me,
  board[[i, j]] = me;
  currentPlayer = opponent;
  ChannelSend["test", {me, {i, j}}];
  ]

receiver::"hacks" = 
  "Incorrect/illegitmate message received, proceed with caution";

attomHACQ = Function[Null, TrueQ@AtomQ@Unevaluated@#, HoldAllComplete];

validHCMQ[hcm_] :=  
  TrueQ@MatchQ[hcm, 
    HoldComplete@
     System`DisableFormatting@{_Integer?attomHACQ, 
           {_Integer?attomHACQ, _Integer?attomHACQ}}];

receiver[m_] :=
 Module[{sender, i, j, hcm},
  hcm = m["Message"];
  If[
   validHCMQ[hcm]
   ,
   {sender, {i, j}} = ReleaseHold[hcm];
   If[sender == opponent && currentPlayer == opponent, 
    board[[i, j]] = opponent;
    currentPlayer = me;]
   ,
   Message[receiver::"hacks"]
   ]
  ];

Unprotect[$AllowExternalChannelFunctions];
$AllowExternalChannelFunctions = True;

listener = ChannelListen["test", receiver];

me = 1;
opponent = me /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1};
currentPlayer = 1;

board = ConstantArray[0, {11, 11}];
Dynamic[renderBoard[board], TrackedSymbols :> {board}]
```

Now, open another notebook and assign a different kernel to it. Evaluate the same code in the new notebook as for the first one, except set `me = 2` instead of `me = 1`. The result should work like this:

[image: Multiplayer demo]

Comment: It looks like there's another thing I should become familiar with. :)

Comment: I didn't think Mathematica would be a reasonable tool to use and build a version of Catan...seems I might have been wrong

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Ops, fixed it now.

Comment: @C.E. I've edited the answer with a modified version of receiver that validates its input. Please roll back or do another edit if you don't like it. I think  ``HoldComplete@System`DisableFormatting@patt`` can safely be replaced by `_@_@patt` if you find it too long. I figured I would explicitly add ``System`DisableFormatting`` because it is not in the ``System` `` context in a fresh kernel and failing to prefix it with ``System` `` gives a namespace error.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom It's a good edit, showing how to match messages is useful also for cases where several different messages may be sent.

Comment: @C.E. Seems like I botched my previous edit, because we have `MatchQ[Integer[badCode], _Integer]`. I put the user message of receiver before `attomHACQ` to emphasie that `receiver` and `attomHACQ` belong together. If the user forgets to evaluate `attomHACQ` he is vulnerable. Please review my edit, maybe the function names are not very nice etc

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I approve of this edit, nicely done.