# Working with DynamicModule: Tracking the progress of Initialization

Tags: front-end, dynamic, evaluation, gui-construction, scheduling

How to track `Initialization` step by step? Any tricky solution is ok. One condition, `x` should be `DynamicModule` variable.

```
DynamicModule[{x}, 
   Dynamic[x], 
   Initialization :> ( 
      x = 1; 
      Pause@1; 
      x = 2; 
      Pause@1; 
      x = 3; 
   )]
```

I want the progress to be reflected in `Dynamic[x]`.

Comment: You can always use Print :)  `DynamicModule[{x},
 Dynamic[x],
 Initialization :>  
  (x = 1;
   Print["x=2"];
   x = 2;
   Print["x=3"];
   x = 3)
 ]`

Comment: @Nasser Well, right, I should stress out that I want this tracking to be reflected in Dynamic updating :) Moreover, if you riffle your code with `Pause` you can see that it isn't working like one could expect.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by `this tracking to be reflected in Dynamic updating` Since Initialization is processed once from top down. (to generate the initial expression). Once this is done, Initialization basically goes away.

Comment: @Nasser Not 100% true, `Initialization` evaluates every time you open a cdf/nb with visible related `DynamicModule`. I would like to see x switching values while `Initilization` is running. The Dynamic cell is already there, it's just waiting for `Init` to complete, even if you use `SynchronousInitialization->False`. I need it to behave like I've described :)

Comment: I do not think what I said is different from what you are saying. Initialization is evaluated to generate the dynamic expression first time it is needed to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: In other words, dynamic updating of `Dynamic[x]` (I think) waits for the initialization to be completed.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I know for Manipulate that the following happens, and I would assume the same for DyanmicModule, since Manipulate is just a DynamicModule: The body of Manipulate (the expression part) is checked for valid input/form, but it is not evaluated until Initialization is finished. The question of when Initialization is run or not is separate. But when it needs to be evaluated, then yes, the body/dynamics/expression will wait until Initialization is finished running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### tl;dr;

Use `SynchronousInitialization -> False` and, in case of simple `Dynamic[x]`, add `TrackedSymbols`: `Dynamic[x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]` due to the bug mentioned below.

---

Finally I'm able to answer my question with understanding. Two years, no big deal :)

So I want `Dynamic[x]` to reflect the state of the initialization. The last example in WReach's answer does what I need but in a way I don't like. `Dynamic` with `UpdateInterval->0` is a flood of unnecessary calls. Which will still be performed till that `Dynamic` is visible.

#### My understanding and solution to the problem

According to my explanation in:

- [**Synchronizing Dynamics with other preemptive evaluations**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120414/5478)

**all we need is** to make `Initialization` code to be evaluated through the *MainLink*. **`SynchronousInitialization -> False`** serves that purpose.

**Yet that fix is not working**, we still see the initial value and then only the very last at the end.

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
 
 Dynamic[x],
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 Initialization :> (
   x = 1; Pause@1;  x = 2; Pause@1;   x = 3
  )
 ]
```

At this point, a beginner's morale will drop. This should work. Why isn't it? The answer is, come to StackExchange more often. There is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) which interferes:

- [**What is the difference between `Dynamic[x]` and `Dynamic[ h[x] ]` for DynamicModule variables?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/5478)

So my minimal example was too minimal:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
 
 Dynamic[ x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}], 
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 Initialization :> (
   x = 1; Pause@1;
   x = 2; Pause@1;
   x = 3
   )
 ]
```

Probably the most verbose solution is `Dynamic[x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]` which appears to be superfluous but at least it is clear.

Use whatever you want but there is usually something more than `x` so that bug can be missed.

Uff, works and fits my understanding of *Kernel*-*FrontEnd* communication.

---

#### Real life example

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, init = False},
 Dynamic[
  If[
    init,
    Overlay[{
      Dynamic@ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"], 
      Dynamic[x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
      }, All, 1, Alignment -> Center,  BaseStyle -> 18
    ],
    x
  ],
  TrackedSymbols :> {init, x}
 ],
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 Initialization :> (
   init = True;
   x = 1; Pause@1;
   x = 2; Pause@1;
   x = 3; Pause[1];
   init = False;
   )]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

By default, `DynamicModule` uses `SynchronousInitialization -> True`.  This causes the initialization to be performed on the preemptive link, disabling any updates to the front-end.  In particular, print statements, cell creation and dynamic box updates will all be deferred until the initialization completes.

If we wish to monitor that initialization within the notebook itself, we must turn off synchronous initialization.  If we do so, then any of a number of strategies are possible, such as...

... using `Monitor` to watch `x` change within a temporary cell:

```
DynamicModule[{x}
, Dynamic[x]
, SynchronousInitialization -> False
, Initialization :> Monitor[x = 1; Pause@1; x = 2; Pause@1; x = 3, x]
]
```

... or `CellPrint` to watch `x` change within a permanent cell:

```
DynamicModule[{x}
, Dynamic[x]
, SynchronousInitialization -> False
, Initialization :>
    (CellPrint@Dynamic@x; x = 1; Pause@2; x = 2; Pause@2; x = 3)
]
```

... or even simply using `Print` to print out some intermediate information:

```
DynamicModule[{x}
, Dynamic[x]
, SynchronousInitialization -> False
, Initialization :>
    (x = 1; Print@"1st"; Pause@2; x = 2; Print@"2nd"; Pause@2; x = 3)
]
```

We can even monitor the initialization of `x` from within the `DynamicModule` by overriding the default `UpdateInterval -> Infinity` on `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{x}
, Dynamic[x, UpdateInterval -> 0]
, SynchronousInitialization -> False
, Initialization :> (x = 1; Pause@1; x = 2; Pause@1; x = 3)
, UnsavedVariables :> {x}
]
```

It is necessary to add `x` to the list of `UnsavedVariables` because without it the value of `x` will not be seen to change dynamically when the output cell is re-initialized in a new front-end session.

**For Debugging Purposes**

If debugging messages are our goal, and if it is not acceptable to perform asynchronous initialization for some reason, then a simple solution would be to write logging messages to an external file.  That file could then be monitored in real-time using an external utility like *tail*.

It is possible, if ambitious, to use `Mathlink` to send debugging messages to a second front-end.  See, for example, the chat application in this [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44027/142).  Personally, I think this is overkill.  I would probably spend the time getting the `DynamicModule` to work with asynchronous initialization instead.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to such tracking to be reflected inside the `DynamicModule` in bahaviour of it`s variables?

Comment: @Kuba Yes.  Please see the new variation using `UpdateInterval`.