# Bug with Initialization in DynamicModule?

Tags: dynamic

In exploring [Working with DynamicModule: Tracking the progress of Initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59949/tracking-initialization), I came across this.  The following usually shows a value for `x` of `300000` to `400000` after initialization.  It varies each time.

```
DynamicModule[{x}, Dynamic[x], Initialization :> (x = 1;
   Do[x = i, {i, 10000000}];
   x = 2;
   Do[x = i, {i, 10000000}];
   x = 3;)]
```

If the option `SynchronousInitialization -> True` is set, a similar thing happens, although the displayed value for `x` ranged from `18000` to `9900000`.  On the other hand, if `SynchronousInitialization -> False` is set, the displayed value is `3`, as expected.

Is this a bug, or is it to be expected, due to some aspect of the dynamic updating system I'm not aware of?

Version: 10.0.0, 9.0.1, and 8.0.4; Max OSX 10.9.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SynchronousInitialization -> True` causes dynamic evaluations to occur on the preemptive link.  This locks up the notebook front-end for the duration of an evaluation.  To avoid locking up the front-end indefinitely, there is a default timeout of six seconds:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DynamicEvaluationTimeout]
(* 6. *)
```

The values we see for `x` are simply those that have been set prior to the timeout.

On my machine, it takes about 25 seconds to perform the complete initialization.  If I set the timeout to a value higher than that, then I get the expected result:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], {DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 60}]
```

The original motivation for this question aside, it is generally inadvisable to perform long-running evaluations synchronously on the preemptive link.  It is especially dangerous to set the timeout to infinity or a large number because it disables the ability to terminate a runaway calculation.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this must be right.  When I first noticed, I had timed the do-loop at just under a second and substituted it for `Pause[1]`.  This morning it's taking 2.6 sec. and the complete initialization code on its own takes 5.3 sec.  If I put `SessionTime[]` in cells before and after the `DynamicModule`, the difference is slightly over 6 sec.  I knew about the time constraint, but thought I was within that time.  I must have been mistaken last night about the timing of the loop.  I also thought there would be a warning if it timed out.