# How to express calculation time with ProgressIndicator

Tags: display, timing, cdfplayer

How to express calculation time with ProgressIndicator.

I want to make the following CDF document.

```
 Manipulate[ 
     db = Table[ test2[i, number], {i, 2, end}]
   ; pos = Position[ db, True]
   ; seq = Table[ db[[pos[[i, 1]]]][[1]], {i, 1, Length[pos]}]

   , {{end, 1000, ""}, {1000, 2000, 3000}}
   , {{number, 3, ""}, {3, 4, 5}}
   , TrackedSymbols :> {end, number}
   , Initialization :> (
         test2[n_, number_] := Module[{}, 
             exp = Factor[x^n - 1]
           ; data = Table[CoefficientList[exp[[i]] , x], {i, 1, Length[exp], 1}]
           ; t1 = Table[MemberQ[Flatten@data, i], {i, number, number}]
           ; If[ MemberQ[ Flatten@t1, True], {n, True}, {n, False}]];
     ) 
]
```

Plugging in and running the above CDF document into a web page takes a lot of computation time.

At this time, I would like to show the `ProgressIndicator` in the proper position during the calculation.

[image]

Because the user wants to know whether the calculation is in progress or whether the calculation is complete.

How can I express the information that the calculation is in progress or finished with `ProgressIndicator`?

Comment: related: [Tracking the progress of Initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59949/5478) or [Button action monitored with progress bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5478)

Answer (score 5):

You can use another `ProgressIndicator` with an `Indeterminate` range option. The latter will show "running" without a specific value:

```
Column@{
  ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[n], {1, 100}], 
  ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[n], Indeterminate]
  }
Table[(n = k; Pause[0.1]), {k, 1, 100}];
```

Alternatively, you can just write "Running..." and switch that to "done" when done:

```
Row@{ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[n], {1, 100}], " ", Dynamic[status]}
status = "Running...";
Table[(n = k; Pause[0.1]), {k, 1, 100}];
status = "Done!";
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct explanation. I solved the problem thanks to this.