# How to change the label "Evaluating Initialization..." when SynchronousInitialization -> False?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I frequently use `SynchronousInitialization -> False` when I have time consuming initialization in a `Manipulate` expression. I was wondering how I could change the label "Evaluating Initialization..." to, say, "Wait please..."?

```
Manipulate[x, 
 {x, 0, 1}, 
 SynchronousInitialization -> False, 
 Initialization :> (Pause[1])]
```

[image]

Comment: I do not see an option in `SynchronousInitialization` to change this. may be you could send WRI a feature request to add such option to change the message.

Answer (score 2):

#### not recommended approach

With `Method -> {"TemplateExpand" -> True}` you can inspect whole structure of created boxes.

```
ToBoxes[Manipulate[body
, SynchronousInitialization -> False
, Initialization :> (Pause[1])
, Method -> {"TemplateExpand" -> True}
]]
```

and find out that this preview is defined in `` Manipulate`Dump`initDisplay ``. So here's a quick helper function to replace it:

```
replaceInitScreen[
  manipulate_,
  newInit_
] := RawBoxes[
  ToBoxes[manipulate] /. 
   HoldPattern[Manipulate`Dump`initDisplay[False]] -> newInit
]
```

```
replaceInitScreen[
 Manipulate[body, SynchronousInitialization -> False, 
  Initialization :> (Pause[1]), Method -> {"TemplateExpand" -> True}],
 Row[{ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"], "Please wait..."}]
 ]
```

[image]

It works but it is not a recommended way, consider it an exercise.

#### recommended approach

What you should do it to take it in your hands and do something like:

```
DynamicModule[{initDone = False}
, Panel @ Dynamic[
    If[ Not @ TrueQ @ initDone
    , Row[{ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"], "Please wait..."}]
    , body
    ]
  , TrackedSymbols :> {initDone}
  ]
, UnsavedVariables :> {initDone}
, SynchronousInitialization -> False
, Initialization :> (Pause[1]; body = "whatever"; initDone = True)
]
```

Read more in closely related:

[Working with DynamicModule: Tracking the progress of Initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59949/5478)

Comment: I used your code in a simple way, as a "wrapper" with body = Manipulate[...]  and work well as I wanted. Thanks.