# How can I connect to a remote machine?

Tags: remote-access

My friend and I are trying to set up remote kernels.

He has a server at home running 1 kernel off of a Linux-based server. We're both on 8.0.

I manually set `$RemoteCommand` to

```
"ssh `3`@`1`-l `3` \"math -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname \
`2` -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &\""`
```

and manually changed `$RemoteUserName` to the one he set up for me. The problem is, whenever we try and run the code, we get the following error message:

`LaunchRemote::rsh: Command ssh [my username]@[his server address]-l [my username] "math -mathlink -linkmode Connect -linkprotocol TCPIP -linkname 51145@[my public IP address],51146@[my public IP address] -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &" may have failed (exit code 1).`

The problem is, my public IP address is not the same as my private IP address, so I can't connect. How can I get Mathematica to recognize my private IP instead?

Answer (score 13):

Dale Roberts's solution works fine, but only when the remote machine can be seen directly from the Internet. After connection you can type

```
Links[]
```

and see

> {LinkObject["31415@127.0.0.1,31416@127.0.0.1", 3, 1], 
>    LinkObject["36946@109.1.2.3,51520@109.1.2.3", 56, 2], 
>    LinkObject["59488@109.1.2.3,54373@109.1.2.3", 57, 3]}

It means that the main link (the first) was opened through the ssh tunnel, but the preemptive link and the service link (the second and the third) was opened directly to the remote machine (it has 109.1.2.3 ip in this example).

If the remote machine is behind a router with port redirection this approach is unfortunately not worked. It is because `MathLink` naively try to open the preemptive link and the service link to the remote machine ip which is now something like 192.168.1.123. This behaviour can not be changed from extarnal options like `LinkName` and `LinkHost`.

I found great solution here: [Remote Kernel Strategies](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/). It simply redefines `` MathLink`CreateFrontEndLink ``. It was written for Mathematica 6, but it also works with Mathematica 9.

Now I can connect and see that all connections are through the ssh tunnel

```
Links[]
```

> {LinkObject["37174@127.0.0.1,39928@127.0.0.1", 3, 1], 
>    LinkObject["39929@127.0.0.1,39930@127.0.0.1", 57, 2], 
>    LinkObject["39931@127.0.0.1,39932@127.0.0.1", 58, 3]}

For further study, see excellent explanation in *init.m* in [Remote Kernel Strategies](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/).

---

I want to add some information about connecting to and disconnecting from the remote kernel without it's interrupting. It may be useful if you want to send a long task, turn off local machine and reconnect to the remote machine several days later.

I don't know the best place to post this information. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/612/connecting-to-and-disconnecting-from-a-continuously-running-kernel-on-demand) question is about connecting to the master kernel on the server while the subkernels are running. So I will be happy if you correct me.

I modify the last command in `tunnel.sh` in [Remote Kernel Strategies](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/) in the following way:

```bash
/usr/bin/ssh \
 $SSH_OPTS \
 -R 127.0.0.1:$MAIN_LINK_DATA_PORT:127.0.0.1:$MAIN_LINK_DATA_PORT \
 -R 127.0.0.1:$MAIN_LINK_MESSAGE_PORT:127.0.0.1:$MAIN_LINK_MESSAGE_PORT \
 -L $PREEMPTIVE_LINK_DATA_PORT:127.0.0.1:$PREEMPTIVE_LINK_DATA_PORT \
 -L $PREEMPTIVE_LINK_MESSAGE_PORT:127.0.0.1:$PREEMPTIVE_LINK_MESSAGE_PORT \
 -L $SERVICE_LINK_DATA_PORT:127.0.0.1:$SERVICE_LINK_DATA_PORT \
 -L $SERVICE_LINK_MESSAGE_PORT:127.0.0.1:$SERVICE_LINK_MESSAGE_PORT \
 $REMOTE_KERNEL_HOST \
 "screen -wipe; \
 screen -ls | grep MathKernel -q || \
 screen -md -S MathKernel $REMOTE_KERNEL_PATH && \
 screen -md -S Respawner screen -x MathKernel; \ 
 sleep 1; \
 screen -S MathKernel -X stuff `echo -e \"\\\\\\\$ParentLink=LinkCreate[\\\\\\\"$LINK_NAME\\\\\\\",LinkMode-\\\\\\\>Connect,LinkProtocol-\\\\\\\>\\\\\\\"TCPIP\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\;\\\r\"`; \
 sleep 20" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

It starts [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session with `MathKernel` name if it isn't exist. Then it connects to the existing session by

```
$ParentLink=LinkCreate["$LINK_NAME",LinkMode->Connect,LinkProtocol->"TCPIP"];
```

Without `sleep` Mathematica doesn't have time to establish the connection.
For disconnecting I use

```
SetAttributes[Disconnect, HoldAll];
Disconnect[expr___] :=
 Module[{links = {$ParentLink, MathLink`$ServiceLink,
     MathLink`$PreemptiveLink}}, $ParentLink = Null;
  LinkClose /@ links; MathLink`$PortNumber =.; SetOptions["stdout", FormatType->OutputForm];
  expr]
```

Then you can simply run something like this

```
x = Sum[EulerPhi[n], {n, 10000000}]; // Disconnect
```

and `x=...` will be evaluated after disconnection. `` MathLink`$PortNumber =. `` is necessary to connect to the same ports after disconnecting. For convenience`Disconnect` can be added to `init.m`.

*Update 1:* you have to run two `screen` sessions and attach one to another because you can send commands only to attached sessions. You can directly connect to the `screen` session by `screen -x MathKenel`. It is useful if you want to check the state of your program from the mobile phone.

*Update 2:* `LinkClose/@Links[]` is bad because it closes links to parallel subkernels. So I explicitly specify `$ParentLink`, `` MathLink`$ServiceLink ``, and `` MathLink`$PreemptiveLink ``.

*Update 3:* Explicit port specification isn't needed.

*Update 4:* The terminal formatting is restored by `SetOptions["stdout", FormatType->OutputForm]`. Thanks [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32167/4678) answer.

*Update 5:* After reconnection custom syntax highlighting is dropped. You can repair it by

```
Scan[ToExpression[#, InputForm, 
    Function[name, 
     SyntaxInformation@Unevaluated[name] = 
      SyntaxInformation@Unevaluated[name], HoldAll]] &, 
  Names["Global`*"]];
```

*Update 6:* *Mathematica* 10 has libraries which can be incompatible with our SSH. If you have an error

> ssh: symbol lookup error: ssh: undefined symbol: EVP_aes_128_ctr

or something like this then reset an environmental variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by adding

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
```

to `tunnel.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's very helpful for me. I actually also use the Remote Kernel Strategies to connect to the remote kernel. On our university super computer, the TCPIP communication seem to have been blocked. And using the package, I was able to connect my local frontend to the remote main kernel. But the TCPIP communication between the remote master kernel and the subkernels is also blocked. Do you know how to let the communication between subkernel and main kernel also through ssh?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Please could you take a look at my follow up question? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90051/reconnecting-to-remote-kernels-through-ssh-tunnelling

Comment: No longer works in v11 either.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution that works in 13.x?

Answer (score 8):

I've been successful connecting to my office Mac workstation using SSH port forwarding:

```bash
ssh -R 31415:127.0.0.1:31415 -R 31416:127.0.0.1:31416 username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -mathlink -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName 31415@127.0.0.1,31416@127.0.0.1 -LinkHost 127.0.0.1"
```

where `username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` should be replaced with your SSH user name and the IP address of the remote machine. If the remote machine is running Linux, replace

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel
```

with the appropriate path of the MathKernel executable.

Comment: So `31415` and `31416` are ports.. ARe these default values? Can I do something similar to start a remote kernel in my notebook/script?

Comment: You can change those port numbers to anything. Yes, you should be able to use the same to start a remote kernel in your notebook/script.

Comment: can you give more details on how/where you use the command?

Answer (score 2):

I have never had luck with this directly, since the remote machine has to connect back to the master.  However, there is a way to do it with OpenVPN -- make the two machines connect to the VPN appear to be on the same subnet.

Comment: and just to add -- you might think that you can do port forwarding through your router.  But it often doesn't work because of ISP port-blocking policies.  Also, I have never gotten the ssh forwarding stuff to work, either.