# Getting a remote kernel from a machine not directly reachable

Tags: remote-access

I have a machine capable of running *Mathematica* on 24 cores which I would like to take advantage of :) The only problem is that this is a remote machine to which I cannot connect *directly*, I have to pass through a front-end machine first.

My computer (A) can connect to (B) and (B) can ssh to (C), which is the powerful machine, but my computer connect directly to (C).

Any suggestions how I could make this connection?

Comment: It can be done using "ssh tunneling", which allows mapping some ports of C to B.  The "remote kernel strategies" package by Sascha Kratky makes this easier.  This should get you started, but I expect the process to be messy.  Unfortunately I don't have the time to figure out a complete working answer, it would take quite  bit of work and experimenting, just too much time.

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11682/12

Comment: opening a tunnel on machine B sounds like a good strategy. I'll work on that and we will see how far I get ...

Comment: I am terribly bad writer. my issue has only in part to do with (C) being hidden to (A). I realized that tunneling does not help because (B) access to (C) by submitting a job to an interactive LSF queue ... not quite the same as ssh tunnel. In any case I can open a MathKerel running on (C) with a ssh command issued on (A). I guess this is all that matters ... the question now is hot make Mathematica FrontEnd on (A) work with this MathKernel from (C)

Comment: Take a look at [sakra's comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6226196/695132) as well, it links to a newer version of the package.  What it does is precisely let you connect the front end on A to the kernel on C.  The reason why I couldn't use it at the time when I asked the question was that my front end (version 8) kept locking up on a 32-bit Windows XP.  Supposedly this problem should be gone in newer 64-bit versions but I never tried it.  I always felt that it was just too much trouble.  What I do instead is run non-interactively on the fast computer, ...

Comment: ... save the results, and send them back for plotting.

Comment: @RobertoFranceschini Please move your comments to the question body :)