# Is it possible to speed up ContourPlot on multi-core machines?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, parallelization

It is not very difficult to face a function for which `ContourPlot` works too slow. And it seems natural that this function can be parallelized well. Anyway, naive `Parallelize@ContourPlot` produces "*ContourPlot[...] cannot be parallelized;* "...

So, is it possible to parallelize ContourPlot?

Comment: Have you tried generating a discrete mesh and using `ListContourPlot` instead? The mesh does not have to be regular.

Comment: @Verbeia: actually I have not. You suggest generate points using `ParallelMap` and then plot them?

Comment: Yes, that is what I had in mind. I wasn't sure if that was worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @verbeia I assume that would work, but it would mean you work on a regular grid. It doesn't use adaptive gridding  that ContourPlot applies to increase sample density in rapidly changing spots. So the result can be rather different.

Comment: @Sjoerd one could use Szabolcs's approach here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216/adaptive-sampling-for-slow-to-compute-functions-in-2d

Comment: @Verbeia this is a good idea, thank you!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I know, but see my answer referencing another question that dealt with the issue. `ListContourPlot` can use an irregular grid, so it comes down to how you generate the points. But without knowing what the function is, it is hard to know how to proceed.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some working code.  I am also interested in all better solutions, so please ping me if you find any.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I second @Verbeia's suggestion: compute the function on a mesh of points and use `ListContourPlot`.  The disadvantage is that `ListContourPlot` has no adaptive sampling, so it'd be preferable if we could do our own adaptive sampling somehow.  Adaptive sampling can give you a much better result while needing to compute the function in far less points---and the problem here is indeed computation time.  So `ContourPlot` with its adaptive sampling might give a better result in less time on a single CPU than `ListContourPlot` will with a high resolution mesh computed on many CPUs.

Adaptive sampling is what I asked about (and solved) here:  [Adaptive sampling for slow to compute functions in 2D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216/adaptive-sampling-for-slow-to-compute-functions-in-2d/)

The method I implemented there is usable (I am using it for something very similar to what you describe) but it is not nearly as good as `ContourPlot`'s own.  So one might still try to somehow make use of it.  I'm quoting one suggestion I received from Leonid Shifrin there (in a comment):

> You probably can control the `DensityPlot`, although not directly. Since
>   it calls your function, you can simply `Sow` the values until some
>   criteria (which you define) is violated (or satisfied). Then, you stop
>   via [throwing an exception](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Throw.html), and catching it in the outer function, but
>   still inside `Reap`. Alternatively, you could just start fooling
>   `DensityPlot` by supplying faked values (perhaps, interpolated, or
>   whatever), and it will stop by itself, I guess. Not sure this will
>   work for you, but it may be worth trying.

I have not tried to implement this before, but I think it could work if your function is *sufficiently smooth* (which mine is definitely not, but yours may be).

Here's a quick sample implementation of how it could work:

First, let's define a sample function to plot:

```
fun[{x_, y_}] := 1/(1 + Exp[10 (Norm[{x, y}] - 3)])
```

Let's divide both the $x$ and $y$ axes into 5 parts on the interval $[0,5]$ and generate a mesh of points:

```
initialDivision = Range[0, 5];

points = N@Tuples[initialDivision, {2}];
```

Calculate function values on the intial mesh.  This can be parallelized (just use `ParallelMap`)

```
values = fun /@ points;
```

This counter `i` will be used to control the maximal subdivisions in `ContourPlot`:

```
i = 0;
```

Now put the following code into a single cell, and evaluate it several times.  Each time a finer and finer approximation will be computed.  The points where function values have been computed will also be visualized.  Note that I fixed the plot points in `ContourPlot` to force it to use the same initial mesh that I used, and I also fixed the number of contours.

```
if = Interpolation@ArrayFlatten[{{points, List /@ values}}]

{plot, {newpoints}} = Reap[
   ContourPlot[if[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
    Contours -> Range[0, 1, .1], MaxRecursion -> (++i), 
    PlotPoints -> Length[initialDivision], 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]
   ];
plot

newpoints = Complement[newpoints, points];
newvalues = fun /@ newpoints;  (* <-- this can be parallelized *)
points = Join[points, newpoints];
values = Join[values, newvalues];

Graphics[Point[points]]
```

After a few iterations the contour plot and the point mesh will look like this (note that the code above only plots the contours for the *previous* step, not the current results):

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

After 3 iterations, this method has computed the function value in `3809` points for this particular function.

Let's compare this with a plain `ContourPlot` using the same parameters:

```
ContourPlot[fun[{x, y}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
    PlotPoints -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The quality of the plot is about the same with a plain `ContourPlot` as well.

How many points did the plain `CountoutPlot` use?

```
Reap[ContourPlot[fun[{x, y}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 6, 
    MaxRecursion -> 3, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]][[2, 1]] // Length

(* ==> 3790 *)
```

It uses almost the same number of points, so if the bottleneck is computing `f`, the method I described is going to be almost as fast as `ContourPlot` on a single core, with the advantage that it is parallelizable for multiple cores.

The next step would be packaging this up into a self-contained function, but seeing how the quality improves step by step is also valuable as you can make decisions about when to stop calculating (and avoid excessive computation times).

---

I find it quite disappointing that all those nice and fast algorithms that plotting functions use (fast Voronoi cells, Delaunay trinagulation, adaptive sampling) are not directly accessible by users.  We either have to use hacks to access these algorithms or reimplement them.

Comment: Very nice! I thought it could work, but now you've implemented this, which is much better than just an idea. +1.

Comment: I liked the idea. I'll try to make it neater and post it in a little while

Comment: The first time I read this, I missed the fact that you were pulling the point info from `ContourPlot` instead of calculating it on your own. Clever.

Answer (score 17):

One idea, which was originally appealing to me, was to simply split the plot domain in four quarter size pieces and have these pieces calculated in parallel using `ParallelTable` and then combined using `Show`. It appears though that the overhead of getting the graphics data back to Show is pretty large, so this only yields some extra speed if the function is computationally slow.

```
a = 36;
(parPlot = Show[
     ParallelTable[
      RegionPlot[
       Mod[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 7/2 ArcTan[x, y] +Sin[x] +Cos[y], \[Pi]] < \[Pi]/2, 
       {x, -a + i a, a + i a}, {y, -a + i a, a + i a}, 
       PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-a, a}}, PlotPoints -> 50], 
       {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}]
     ]); // AbsoluteTiming

{25.5344605, Null}

parPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The original serial calculation:

```
a = 36;
g = RegionPlot[
    Mod[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 7/2 ArcTan[x, y] + Sin[x] + 
       Cos[y], \[Pi]] < \[Pi]/2, {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*
==> {51.2839332, Null}
*)

g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's twice as slow, but it looks slightly better in places. RegionPlot is worse than ContourPlot in this sense.

Answer (score 10):

Try generating a mesh of points using `ParallelMap` and then plot them using `ListContourPlot`.

You might find the techniques in [this question on adaptive sampling for hard-to-compute functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216/8) useful.

Answer (score 10):

The Presentations Application (which I am the author of) has a few routines to aid in the parallel processing of graphics.

Here is a serial contour plot of a complex function. (Presentations has routines for drawing complex functions directly with complex variables.)

```
<<Presentations`

Module[{f = z \[Function] Sin[z/2], z, zmin = 0, zmax = 4 (1 + I)},
   serial0 =
    Draw2D[
     {ComplexCartesianContour[f[z], {z, zmin, zmax}, Abs,
       Contours -> Range[0, 4, 0.1],
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
       ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {0, 4}]] &),
       PlotPoints -> 5,
       MaxRecursion -> 4]},
     Frame -> True,
     ImageSize -> 300]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
serial0

{0.298017, Null}
```

[image]

The following statement parallel loads all the Presentations package routines to the processors.

```
ParallelLoadPresentations[]
```

The following routine will subdivide the complex plane into rectangular regions.

`ComplexParallelPartitionDomain[{var, nRe, nIm, start, end, overlap}]` will generate a list of nRe x nIm complex subiterators in the form `{{var, start1, end1},...}` for partitioning complex drawing object domains. The parameter overlap has a default value of 0 but otherwise may be used to overlap each subdomain except on the right and top boundaries.

Here, since I have six processors, we will use

```
ComplexParallelPartitionDomain[{z, 2, 3, 0, 4 (1 + I), 0}]
{{z, 0, 2 + (4 I)/3}, {z, (4 I)/3, 2 + (8 I)/3},
 {z, (8 I)/3, 2 + 4 I}, {z, 2, 4 + (4 I)/3},
 {z, 2 + (4 I)/3, 4 + (8 I)/3}, {z, 2 + (8 I)/3, 4 + 4 I}}
```

I find that a convenient way to do parallel processing is to use the `ParallelSubmit` and `WaitAll` mechanism. Here is the code for the parallel processing version.

```
Module[{f = z \[Function] Sin[z/2], z, zmin = 0, zmax = 4 (1 + I)},
   par1 =
    Draw2D[
     {WaitAll[
       ParallelSubmit[{f},
          ComplexCartesianContour[f[z], #, Abs,
           Contours -> Range[0, 4, 0.1],
           ColorFunctionScaling -> False,

           ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
               Rescale[#, {0, 3.7}]] &),
           PlotPoints -> 6,
           MaxRecursion -> 3]] & /@ 
        ComplexParallelPartitionDomain[{z, 2, 3, 0, 4 (1 + I), 0}]
       ]},
     Frame -> True,
     ImageSize -> 300]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
par1
{0.101006, Null}
```

[image]

Next I will try Sjoerd's example above.

```
region = {x, y} \[Function] (Mod[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 7/2 ArcTan[x, y] + Sin[x] + 
      Cos[y], \[Pi]] < \[Pi]/2)

(serial1 = RegionPlot[region[x, y], {x, -35, 35}, {y, -35, 35},
     PlotPoints -> 20,
     MaxRecursion -> 5]); // AbsoluteTiming
serial1
{44.546548, Null}
```

[image]

There is a similar partitioning function for x-y domains.

```
ParallelPartitionDomain[{x, 2, -35, 35, 0}, {y, 3, -35, 35, 0}]
{{{x, -35, 0}, {y, -35, -(35/3)}}, {{x, -35, 0}, {y, -(35/3), 35/3}},
 {{x, -35, 0}, {y, 35/3, 35}}, {{x, 0, 35}, {y, -35, -(35/3)}},
 {{x, 0, 35}, {y, -(35/3), 35/3}}, {{x, 0, 35}, {y, 35/3, 35}}}
```

There is one problem with partitioning `RegionPlot`s in this way. If we want the automatic outlining of the region, then with partitioning we obtain some boundary lines on the edges of the partition. These are also on the edges of the serial plot but much less noticable. Drawing the boundary lines definitely improves the image. One way to handle this is to use a darker color for the region and the same color for the boundary lines.

```
par2 =
   Draw2D[
    {WaitAll[
      ParallelSubmit[{region},
         RegionDraw[region[x, y], Evaluate[Sequence @@ #], 
          MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 20,
          PlotStyle -> Darker@Orange,
          BoundaryStyle -> Darker@Orange]] & /@ 
       ParallelPartitionDomain[{x, 2, -35, 35, 0}, {y, 3, -35, 35, 0}]
      ]},
    Frame -> True,
    ImageSize -> 350]; // AbsoluteTiming
par2
{2.196126, Null}
```

[image]

Notice that we obtained a speedup of a factor of 20, despite using only six processors, and the Parallel Kernel Status showing a speedup of 5.45. This is because we were able to use much less recursion to obtain the same quality of plot. These comparisions are a bit tricky because we have to compare the two plots by eye and we have two variables, `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` to adjust. Nevertheless, a smaller piece of a plot will generally be topologically simpler and we can often achieve speedups that exceed the number of processors.

Answer (score 6):

The following version is a mixture between Sjoerd's answer and Szabolcs answer. I'm using the `CountorPlot` example, and not the `RegionPlot` example, since I believe there's a bug on the `EvaluationMonitor` option of the `RegionPlot` (and also, because there's no such thing as a ListRegionPlot).

First, I start by making the function a little slower, just to be on a "real" scenario.

```
fun[{x_, y_}] := (Pause[0.001]; 1/(1 + Exp[10 (Norm[{x, y}] - 3)]))
```

The method is straightforward (and if someone is willing to make my code simpler, please go ahead). We just divide the 2D space.

Let's start by the serial case for speed benchmarking:

```
AbsoluteTiming@ContourPlot[fun[{x, y}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
 Contours -> Range[0, 1, .1], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> {6, 6}, Frame -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 200, ClippingStyle -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

Now, we parallelize it:

```
coreMesh = {10, 10};
xRange = {0, 5};
yRange = {0, 5};
totalPlotPoints = {6, 6};
GraphicsGrid[allPlots = ParallelTable[
 ContourPlot[
  fun[{x, y}],
   {x, (xI - 1) (xRange[[2]] - xRange[[1]])/coreMesh[[1]],
    xI (xRange[[2]] - xRange[[1]])/coreMesh[[1]]},
   {y, (yI - 1) (yRange[[2]] - yRange[[1]])/coreMesh[[2]],
    yI (yRange[[2]] - yRange[[1]])/coreMesh[[2]]}, 
 Contours -> Range[0, 1, .1], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 PlotPoints -> {Max[2, Floor[totalPlotPoints[[1]]/coreMesh[[1]]]], 
  Max[2, Floor[totalPlotPoints[[2]]/coreMesh[[2]]]]}, 
 Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Floor[200/coreMesh[[1]]], 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic], {yI, coreMesh[[2]], 1, -1}, {xI, 1, 
 coreMesh[[1]]}], Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

```
Show[allPlots, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

I get similar artefacts as the ones identified by Sjoerd for the `RegionPlot`.

On this speed testing case, I'm going to divide on a coarser mesh (and I slightly improved the code readability).

```
coreMesh = {4, 4};
xRange = {0, 5};
yRange = {0, 5};
{stepX, stepY} = {(xRange[[2]] - xRange[[1]])/coreMesh[[1]],
 (yRange[[2]] - yRange[[1]])/coreMesh[[2]]};
totalPlotPoints = {6, 6};
{time, allPoints} =AbsoluteTiming@Flatten[ParallelTable[Reap[
 ContourPlot[z = fun[{x, y}],
  {x, (xI - 1) stepX, xI*stepX}, {y, (yI - 1) stepY, yI*stepY}, 
  Contours -> Range[0, 1, .1], MaxRecursion -> 3, 
  PlotPoints -> {Max[2,Floor[totalPlotPoints[[1]]/coreMesh[[1]]]], 
    Max[2, Floor[totalPlotPoints[[2]]/coreMesh[[2]]]]}, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, z}]]][[2, 1]],
{yI, coreMesh[[2]], 1, -1}, {xI, 1, coreMesh[[1]]}], 2];



{time, Length[allPoints]}
(*{1.82858, 4472}*)
```

A little more points, and yet, less than half the time (on 8 threads...). I got the best performance on a 3 by 3 mesh, but since the amount of points was smaller, the comparison wouldn't be honest.

```
Graphics[Point[allPoints[[All, {1, 2}]]], ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Putting all points together:

```
AbsoluteTiming@ListContourPlot[allPoints, Contours -> Range[0, 1, .1], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 200
]
```

[image]

So, on total, 2.1 seconds, instead of 5.4 seconds. Not huge... but this method is very susceptible to non optimized work balances, since all the complexity may end up being on just one kernel (which, on this example, is not very far from the truth).