# How to sample a function as Plot* functions do?

Tags: plotting

Suppose we have a hard to calculate function `f`. We plot it like e.g.

```
Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},MaxRecursion->5,PlotPoints->30,PlotRange->All]
```

After some long calculation this gives us a nice image, it can be rotated and all, but suddenly we want to look at a density plot of `f`. We can of course repeat the whole long calculation with `DensityPlot`, but it's wasteful. We could instead have pre-calculated a table of values of `f` using `Table`, but this would imply homogeneous (or some manually-parametrized) grid, which can be an inefficient (or hard to implement) choice for many functions.

So what is needed is a way to sample the function as e.g. `Plot3D` would do it with given `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints`, but instead of putting the result into a graphics box, put it into a variable as a list of coordinates or whatever form suitable for `List*Plot*` family of functions. How can this be done?

Comment: Make an appromixation, e.g. `f2 = FunctionInterpolation[f[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]` and use that in the plots.

Comment: @Coolwater but `FunctionInterpolation` doesn't seem to have controls over how it samples the function.

Comment: Take a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216/12 and here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1011/12  I recommend the second.  The first has issues.  I have a much more complex solution to the first one which unfortunately was too messy and too involved to post here ...

Comment: The title would seem to be duplicate of these: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82912/how-to-obtain-adaptive-sampling-as-in-plot-function, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88299/how-to-implement-the-sample-point-process-like-the-built-ins-of-mathematica -- maybe indicate it's higher dimensional sampling or 2D sampling that you're interested in, whichever is more accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say for example :

```
 gr00 = Plot3D[
            Sin[x y],
            {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
            MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The data, including the mesh, are the first element of `GraphicsComplex[...]` in `gr00` :

```
gr00 // InputForm // Short
```

[image]

Then :

```
ListDensityPlot[gr00[[1, 1]]]
```

[image]

```
ListDensityPlot[gr00[[1, 1]], Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

You can even do a copy-paste of your graphic inside the `ListDensityPlot`, the data are not lost :

[image]

> --> same result as above

Comment: I like this, but it does depend on the internal, undocumented  structure of an object

Comment: @mikado The doc of Plot3D says : "Plot3D returns `GraphicsComplex[data]]`" without saying what is exactly data. You can use a more robust extraction of data with something like `Cases[...,GraphicsComplex[___],{1,Infinity}]`. The philosophy not do mix data and presentation (tick...) is stable on mathematica since the beginning. I think that the main risk is to have the `Graphics[...]` form instead of `GraphicsComplex` (see `Normal[ComplexExpand[..]]`), because `GraphicsComplex[]`  was only introduced in 2007. So effectively, I only use this is interactive sessions.