# Saving the data that was used to generate ListLinePlot in notebook?

Tags: plotting, wolfram-cloud

I periodically summarize my experiments by copying best-looking `ListLinePlot`s into a new notebook and saving it to Wolfram Cloud. What is a good approach to also save the data used to generate the plot? IE, in case I want to regenerate the plot later with different data-range or style.

One potential way, I could just evaluate the data object, and collapse the cell to make it invisible, but not sure how to recover it...would I need to  copy paste the 10MB output cell into input cell and evaluate it to recover the data? So wondering if there are alternative solutions (perhaps along the lines of `Manipulate` which does some magic with `SaveDefinitions->True`)

Comment: I do this: http://szhorvat.net/pelican/save-data-in-notebooks.html  It does work in Wolfram Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your data from the graphic generated by `ListLinePlot`.

Example :

```
ListLinePlot[Sin /@ Range[0,2 Pi,Pi/5]]
```

[image]

Type `gr00=` before your graphic :

[image]

Evaluate the cell :

[image]

Your data are in `gr00` :

```
gr00 // Normal //Cases[#,Line[___],{1,-1}]&
```

[image]

`Normal`is useless here but would be usefull for some graphics generated by somme other functions of the `*Plot*` family (`Plot3D ...`)

[related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125497/5467)