# Improve Plot3D resolution near max/mins

Tags: plotting

I have the following function

$$V(r) = \sum_{i=1}^N 4 \epsilon_i \left(\frac{\sigma_i^{12}}{\|r-r_{0i}\|^{12}}-\frac{\sigma_i^6}{\|r-r_{0i}\|^6}\right)$$

which -for those interested- corresponds to a sum of [Lennard-Jones potentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential), with the following real life set of parameters

```
sig = {0.329633, 0.0400014, 0.405359, 0.235197, 0.387541, 0.235197,
       0.235197, 0.387541, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.387541, 0.235197,
       0.235197, 0.387541, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.329633, 0.0400014,
       0.0400014, 0.0400014, 0.356359, 0.302906, 0.329633, 0.0400014,
       0.387541, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.356359, 0.302906, 0.329633,
       0.0400014, 0.405359, 0.235197, 0.387541, 0.235197, 0.235197,
       0.405359, 0.235197, 0.36705, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.36705,
       0.235197, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.356359, 0.302906, 0.329633,
       0.0400014, 0.405359, 0.235197, 0.387541, 0.235197, 0.235197,
       0.387541, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.356359, 0.302906, 0.329633,
       0.0400014, 0.0400014, 0.356359, 0.302906, 0.329633, 0.0400014,
       0.405359, 0.235197, 0.405359, 0.235197, 0.36705, 0.235197, 0.235197,
       0.235197, 0.387541, 0.235197, 0.235197, 0.36705, 0.235197, 0.235197,
       0.235197, 0.356359, 0.302906}

eps = {0.8368, 0.192464, 0.08368, 0.092048, 0.23012, 0.092048, 0.092048,
       0.23012, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.23012, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.23012,
       0.092048, 0.092048, 0.8368, 0.192464, 0.192464, 0.192464, 0.46024,
       0.50208, 0.8368, 0.192464, 0.23012, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.46024,
       0.50208, 0.8368, 0.192464, 0.08368, 0.092048, 0.23012, 0.092048,
       0.092048, 0.08368, 0.092048, 0.33472, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.092048,
       0.33472, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.46024, 0.50208, 0.8368,
       0.192464, 0.08368, 0.092048, 0.23012, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.23012,
       0.092048, 0.092048, 0.29288, 0.50208, 0.8368, 0.192464, 0.192464,
       0.46024, 0.50208, 0.8368, 0.192464, 0.08368, 0.092048, 0.08368,
       0.092048, 0.33472, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.23012, 0.092048,
       0.092048, 0.33472, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.092048, 0.46024, 0.50208}

r0 = {{0.681, -2.673}, {0.605, -2.736}, {0.715, -2.578}, {0.812, -2.583},
      {0.628, -2.607}, {0.654, -2.698}, {0.533, -2.609}, {0.63, -2.515},
      {0.559, -2.545}, {0.609, -2.423}, {0.763, -2.509}, {0.825, -2.446},
      {0.804, -2.6}, {0.742, -2.461}, {0.709, -2.367}, {0.829, -2.465},
      {0.642, -2.547}, {0.629, -2.515}, {0.675, -2.642}, {0.555, -2.543},
      {0.693, -2.445}, {0.778, -2.359}, {0.585, -2.422}, {0.526, -2.499},
      {0.55, -2.291}, {0.543, -2.236}, {0.459, -2.299}, {0.638, -2.219},
      {0.661, -2.105}, {0.715, -2.293}, {0.688, -2.387}, {0.829, -2.244},
      {0.791, -2.156}, {0.867, -2.346}, {0.893, -2.431}, {0.946, -2.309},
      {0.754, -2.38}, {0.674, -2.422}, {0.697, -2.255}, {0.627, -2.281},
      {0.77, -2.205}, {0.657, -2.197}, {0.802, -2.482}, {0.729, -2.503},
      {0.825, -2.566}, {0.883, -2.448}, {0.956, -2.216}, {1.034, -2.126},
      {0.986, -2.287}, {0.921, -2.356}, {1.104, -2.268}, {1.178, -2.271},
      {1.13, -2.381}, {1.056, -2.379}, {1.217, -2.362}, {1.135, -2.523},
      {1.218, -2.53}, {1.055, -2.534}, {1.137, -2.64}, {1.171, -2.628},
      {1.083, -2.751}, {1.043, -2.753}, {1.08, -2.832}, {1.099, -2.133},
      {1.196, -2.059}, {0.987, -2.095}, {0.911, -2.161}, {0.964, -1.963},
      {1.042, -1.957}, {0.833, -1.955}, {0.818, -1.859}, {0.844, -2.053},
      {0.759, -2.051}, {0.92, -2.024}, {0.861, -2.146}, {0.714, -1.996},
      {0.729, -2.089}, {0.708, -1.934}, {0.581, -1.991}, {0.505, -2.018},
      {0.565, -1.898}, {0.586, -2.053}, {0.98, -1.845}, {1.047, -1.739}}
```

which -again, for those interested- correspond to a 2D projection of the first five residues of a S4S5 [alpha helix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_helix) for the [Kv1.2 Ion Channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2r9r_opm.gif).

Defining $V(r)$ as

```
v[r_, r0_, s_, ep_] := 4 ep (s^12/EuclideanDistance[r, r0]^12 -
                             s^6/EuclideanDistance[r, r0]^6);
```

I can plot the potential with

```
Plot3D[Sum[v[{x, y}, r0[[i]], sig[[i]], eps[[i]]], {i, 1, 84}], 
       {x, -0.5, 2}, {y, -3.5, -1}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.35], Blue], 
       AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {-5, 1}
]
```

obtaining the following output

[image: plot of sum of potentials]

or, using `PlotPoints -> 50`

[image: refined plot of sum of potentials]

where the minima/maxima can be seen really well.

The thing is, I have a lot of these objects, with a lot more elements, and a lot of minima/maxima, in a way that is very expensive for my (old) computer to simply increase `PlotPoints` for smoother graphics, and I was wondering, due the fact that $V(r)$ rapidly decreases, **if there is a way to ask *MMA* to increase resolution near the minima/maxima, and reduce it far from the data set** `r0`.

Hope my question is clear *and interesting*.

**--FINAL EDIT--**

First of all, I want to thank you all for your comments and answers. If I could, I'd accept *all of them*, since each one gave me the insight needed to solve my problem. For obvious reasons, [Silvia's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/improve-plot3d-resolution-near-max-mins/10515#10515) deserves maximum recognition, but readers should also check [PlatoManiac](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/improve-plot3d-resolution-near-max-mins/10417#10417) and 
[Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/improve-plot3d-resolution-near-max-mins/10420#10420) responses, as they will provide a full picture.

Now, to honour the work of all the people involved, I'll show you the beautiful application of the code they've worked out.

Here is a caricaturization of the *S4S5 linker* helix, believed to play a major role in the opening and closing of [voltage gated potassium channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_channel).

[image: S4S5 linker helix]

This helix generates all sort of [van der Waals interactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force), that can be modelled by the [Lennard-Jones potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential).

For specific reasons, I need to see how this potential looks on a given plane, namely the *XY* plane, and it is very important to capture all the maxima and minima of it, as it will provide a full picture of the dynamics in that plane.

Thanks to Silvia's code, one can see:

a view from below of the potential generated by the helix,
[image: View from below]

a sideways view, where the peaks are actually minima,
[image: Sideways veiw, the peaks are actually minima]

and a view form above,

[image: View from above]

What you are seeing is the van der Waals interactions generated by the helix over that plane, and if you're wondering what does that sharp barrier around the helix is, it's the macroscopic consequence of [Pauli's Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle)!

**Thank you all for your help, you've put a big smile on my face!**

Comment: You might already get some speed improvement by defining `expr` and then `Plot3D[expr,...]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks You're right. In my code it's done that way. I guess I didn't gave it importance due that the major delay comes from creating the plot and not from the evaluation of the sum.

Comment: I think generating a custom grid and plotting discrete data by `ListPlot3D` will be good.

Comment: You can squeeze out a little more speed by defining `v` using `Dot` instead of `EuclideanDistance` to avoid all the `Abs` : `v[r_,r0_,s_,ep_]:=4ep(s^12/(#.#&[r-r0])^6-s^6/(#.#&[r-r0])^3)`. It's also worth putting `expr=Expand@Sum[...]`

Comment: @SimonWoods In what way does `Expand@Sum[...]` increases performance? If, instead of `expr`, I define a function for the sum, (i.e. `vTot[r_,r0_,s_,ep_]:=Expand@Sum[...]`, and then do `Plot3d[vTot[...]]`, does it still apply?

Comment: @Pragabhava, `Expand` here just reduces the number of multiplications in the expression, for a minor speed increase. In your definition of `vTot` you have used `SetDelayed` - this is unwise as it means the `Sum` will be recomputed every time you evaluate `vTot`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to emphasize the wanted features, my idea is to manually generate a grid which is fine near the ridge line and sketchy far away:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## 1:

First we define our functions following [Simon's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10414#comment30431_10414):

```
v[r_, r0_, s_, ep_] := 4*ep*(s^12/(#.#&)[r-r0]^(12/2)-s^6/(#.#&)[r-r0]^(6/2))

expr = Sum[v[{x, y}, r0[[i]], sig[[i]], eps[[i]]], {i, 1, 84}]; 

func = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate[expr // Expand]];

funcWrap[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := func[x, y]
```

## 2:

The shape of the plot makes me feel that it's more convenient to work in a polar coordinate system in the $x$-$y$ plane, with `rC` (center of `r0`) as the origin. In order to generate a grid fit for `expr`, two key lines need to be known first: one is the boundary `innerBoundLine` where `expr==2` (because we want to cut the `PlotRange` below $1<2$), and the other is the ridge line `minPointsPolar`, highlighted blue in the plot above:

```
rC = Mean[r0];

innerBoundLine = ContourPlot[funcWrap[x, y] == 2,
   {x, -0.5, 2}, {y, -3.5, -1}, PlotPoints -> 50];

innerBoundPoints = Cases[
     Normal[innerBoundLine[[1]] /.Tooltip[expr_, _] :> expr],
     Line[pts_] :> pts, ∞][[1]] // Most;

innerBoundPointsPolar =
  {Arg[{1, I}.#], Norm@#} &[# - rC] & /@ innerBoundPoints // SortBy[#, First] &;

innerBoundFunc = Interpolation[
   ReplacePart[#,{{1, 2}, {-1, 2}} -> Mean[#[[{1, -1}, 2]]]] &[innerBoundPointsPolar],
   PeriodicInterpolation -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

minPointsPolar = Module[
   {ρmin, linefunc, ρinit},
   Table[ρinit = innerBoundFunc[φ];
    ρmin = ρ /. FindMinimum[ funcWrap @@ (ρ {Cos[φ], Sin[φ]} + rC),
        {ρ, ρinit}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"][[2]];
    {φ, ρmin},
    {φ, 0, 2 π, 1. Degree}]];

minFunc = Interpolation[
   ReplacePart[#, {{1, 2}, {-1, 2}} -> Mean[#[[{1, -1}, 2]]]] &[minPointsPolar],
   PeriodicInterpolation -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

## 3:

Now we can proceed to the grid generation step. Here, four grids with different fineness are generated. `minLineGrid` is near the ridge line and is the finest. From `fineGrid` to `transitionalGrid` to `outlineGrid`, the grids are farther and farther from the ridge, and sketchier and sketchier.

```
minLineGrid = Module[{ρmin, linefunc},
   Table[
     ρmin = minFunc[φ];
     linefunc = Append[#,
         funcWrap @@ #] &[
       ρ {Cos[φ], Sin[φ]} + rC];
     Table[linefunc, {ρ,
       Range[.98, 1.02, .01] ρmin
       }],
     {φ, 0, 2 π, 1. Degree}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
   ];

fineGrid = Module[{ρmin, linefunc, ρinit},
   Table[
     ρinit = innerBoundFunc[φ];
     ρmin = minFunc[φ];
     linefunc = Append[#,
         funcWrap @@ #] &[
       ρ {Cos[φ], Sin[φ]} + rC];
     Table[linefunc, {ρ, Join[
        Rescale[Range[0, 1, .5], {0, 1}, {ρinit, ρmin}],
        Rescale[Range[0, 1, .3], {0, 1}, {ρmin, 1.1 ρmin}]
        ]}],
     {φ, 0, 2 π, 2. Degree}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
   ];

transitionalGrid = Module[{ρmin, linefunc},
   Table[
     ρmin = minFunc[φ];
     linefunc = Append[#,
         funcWrap @@ #] &[
       ρ {Cos[φ], Sin[φ]} + rC];
     Table[linefunc, {ρ,
       Rescale[Range[0, 1, .2], {0, 1}, {1.1 ρmin, 1.5 ρmin}]
       }],
     {φ, 0, 2 π, 5. Degree}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
   ];

outlineGrid = Module[{ρmin, linefunc},
   Table[
     ρmin = minFunc[φ];
     linefunc = Append[#,
         funcWrap @@ #] &[
       ρ {Cos[φ], Sin[φ]} + rC];
     Table[linefunc, {ρ,
       Rescale[Range[0, 1, .5], {0, 1}, {1.5 ρmin, 2}]
       }],
     {φ, 0, 2 π, 20. Degree}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
   ];

dataGrid = Join[outlineGrid, transitionalGrid, fineGrid, minLineGrid];
```

The grid points would look like this in the $x$-$y$ plane:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.001], Black, Point[minLineGrid[[All, 1 ;; 2]]],
  PointSize[.002], Red, Point[fineGrid[[All, 1 ;; 2]]],
  PointSize[.005], Darker@Green, Point[transitionalGrid[[All, 1 ;; 2]]],
  PointSize[.008], Blue, Point[outlineGrid[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 20] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## 4:

Plot the `dataGrid` by `ListPlot3D`:

```
ListPlot3D[dataGrid,
 PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2}, {-3.5, -1}, {-5, 1}},
 ClippingStyle -> Gray, BoundaryStyle -> Blue, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 20] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

($x$,$y$) grid of the plot:

```
ListPlot3D[dataGrid,
 PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2}, {-3.5, -1}, {-5, 1}},
 Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 20] & /@ {x, y}), 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Remarks:** I believe it can be made more adaptive by finding an appropriate coordinate transformation which converts the ridge-line and the outside borders (`-0.5 <= x <= 2 && -3.5 <= y <= -1`) to centered concentric circles, and then generate polar grids in this new coordinate system.

**Edit:** The typical time spent for generating above grids on my computer:

```
Timing[
 rC = Mean[r0];

 ...

 outlineGrid = ...;
 ]
```

> {1.482, Null}

Comment: This looks awesome. I'll be able to test it in a couple of hours and then comment. Thank you.

Comment: @Pragabhava Thanks :) Well I have to say this process highly relies on the special shape of `expr`. If you need more general method, `MaxRecursion` would be handy.

Comment: @Silvia This is really amazing...Cheers!

Comment: Very nice! You might also take a shot at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216/5) (if you haven't seen it already)... I don't think Szabolcs is happy with his solution

Comment: @PlatoManiac Thanks:) I was thinking what if the ridge line is not monodrome for some given polar angles. In that case it looks too onerous for me to find a good coord transformation.

Comment: @R.M I've seen it for days, but haven't got enough time to work on it. But it's really very interesting for me!:)

Comment: @Silvia I get your point but lets try to figure out something in the line of your algorithm so that we have something in our arsenal to even attack general problems for which Plot3D family is too slow. One great article that I found considering http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=383259.383267

Comment: If you got no ACM http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf

Comment: @PlatoManiac Can't open the URL, seems to be [GFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China)ed :( I'll check it tomorrow when I have a proxy at hand. But I can image a full automatical method for general problem would be much more hard. Maybe I can give it a try for cases of continuous functions. And your second URL works fine :D I'll take it to office tomorrow:) Now it's really too late here and I have to sleep now :)

Comment: @Silvia Have a good night then..

Comment: @Plato, you mean the method [GrafEq](http://peda.com/grafeq/) uses? I suppose you could do interval arithmetic in *Mathematica*...

Comment: @PlatoManiac I think the link to [Tupper's thesis](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mooncake/thesis/thesis.html) from his homepage is also worth here. The main problem with his algorithm is that it is not completely given: only the general explanations. Probably because it is a part of commercial program [GrafEq](http://peda.com/grafeq/).

Comment: @PlatoManiac I have read the article today, although not very understand the detail. The examples (especially those in fig.9) are fabulous! If I understand correctly, the article concerns about rendering graph on pixels? Although this topic is indeed fascinating, which I want most would be a high efficient adaptive grid, which I can use as computing grid. But I do see great artistic potential in pixel-wise rendering techniques!! Really thanks for recommendation:D

Comment: @Silvia you are very much welcome. I really want to try this pixel-wise rendering. I will let you know once I get started. Keep in touch!

Comment: @PlatoManiac Absolutely! The examples exhibited in GrafEq's page (I suspect all generated with this tech?) are so beautiful! I would like to try it too when I get time :)

Comment: @Silvia Sorry for the late acceptance, I wanted to show you how useful your code was. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pragabhava You're so welcome :) And it's really VERY nice of you for giving such a wonderful feedback!

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the edit! I always need to improve my English :)

Comment: Glad to help!$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
exp1 = Sum[v[{x, y}, r0[[i]], sig[[i]], eps[[i]]], {i, 1, 84}];
Plot3D[exp1, {x, -0.5, 2}, {y, -3.5, -1}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
  Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]], 
  ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Red}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.95 (1. - z)]], 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {-5, 1}, 
  ClippingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.65], Red], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

> 4.8882796

This takes about $5$ sec. in my PC.
Right combination of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` can help you to have smoother plots. But the more recursion you allow the slower the `Plot3D` evaluates. Same logic is true for `PlotPoints` option.

### **Update**

With `Compile` I could bring this timing to a 2.75 sec.

```
Clear[exp, v];
v[r_, r0_, s_, ep_] := 4 ep (s^12/Norm[r - r0]^12 - s^6/Norm[r - r0]^6);
exp[s1_, s2_] := Sum[v[{s1, s2}, r0[[i]], sig[[i]], eps[[i]]], {i, 1, 84}];
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
             Evaluate@(exp[s1, s2] /. s1 -> x /. s2 -> y), 
             CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed" ];
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[cf] // Short
```

Returning no error and no call to `MainEvaluate`!

```
2 arguments
2 Integer registers
841 Real registers
Underflow checking off
Overflow checking off
Integer overflo...  + R823 + R824 + R825 + R826 + R827 + R828 + R829 + R830 + R732 +
R833 + R834 + R835 + R836 + R837 + R838 + R839
1241    Return
```

Now call `Plot3D`

```
Quiet@Plot3D[cf[x, y], {x, -0.5, 2.}, {y, -3.5, -1.},options]
```

Answer (score 10):

You could try to find the optimal combination of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`. High values of both will give you the prettiest plots, but they will take a lot of time. Often a low number of `PlotPoints` with a higher number of `MaxRecursion` or vice versa will do. Below you will find your plots with a few combinations of these values and the timings needed (given in the plot title)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So, my best bet would be to separate the plot in two: a plot of the annular region starting from inside the singular zone and extending outside as to contain most of the minima/maxima, and the second region where $V$ is slowly varying (i.e. far from `r0`). Then use a convenient combination of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` in the first one, and few `PlotPoints` on the second. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @Pragabhava I believe that could work. Perhaps that the connection of the two will yield visible artifacts.