# Plot more points only in specific region of plot

Tags: plotting

I have the code shown at the bottom of this question which generates a 3D plot. There are locations where the two surfaces you see form cones and touch at infinitesimally small points. These points always occur at z=1 and I have to use many PlotPoints to resolve this touching.

I will be generating thousands of these plots (to form a movie) so need to plot each one as quickly as possible. I would imagine a lot of time would be saved if I used a large number of points only in the regions of interest. Is there a way I can use a large PlotPoints density in a rectangular box that spans the x and y domain but has a small height and is vertically centred around z=1 where I know these points occur (but I don't know their x or y)?

[image]

```
(*The lattice vectors*)
a1 = {Sqrt[3], 0};
a2 = {Sqrt[3]/2, 3/2};

(*Omega/w_0*)
Omega = 0.01;

wp[qx_, qy_, r_] := Module[{},
  q = {qx, qy};

  (*Nearest neighbour vectors*)
  {d1, d2, d3} = # - r & /@ {{0, -1}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}};

  (*The c_j's*)
  {theta, phi} = {0, 0};
  {c1, c2, c3} = (1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] - phi + Pi/2]^2)/
      Norm[#]^3 & /@ {d1, d2, d3};

  modfq = 
   Sqrt[c1^2 + c2^2 + c3^2 + 2 c1 c2 Cos[q.(d1 - d2)] + 
     2 c1 c3 Cos[q.(d1 - d3)] +  2 c2 c3 Cos[q.(d2 - d3)]];
  {Sqrt[1 + 2 Omega modfq], Sqrt[1 - 2 Omega modfq]}
  ]

r = {0, 0};

Timing[
 With[{plotopts = {Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
     Ticks -> {{-Pi, 0, Pi}, {-Pi, 0, Pi}, Automatic}, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, ViewPoint -> {1.43, -2.84, 1.13}, 
     ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}}},
  plot1 = 
   Plot3D[wp[qx, qy, r][[1]], {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, plotopts];
  plot2 = 
   Plot3D[wp[qx, qy, r][[2]], {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, plotopts];
  ]
 ]
plot = 
 Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> {0.96, 1.04}, 
  Ticks -> {{-Pi, 0, Pi}, {-Pi, 0, Pi}}, LabelStyle -> Medium, 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 3}, BoxStyle -> Opacity[0.4]]
```

Note: This question could be a duplicate of [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/specific-initial-sample-points-for-3d-plots), but from what I gathered it was about feeding it a list of points rather than a region? I could be wrong.

Comment: Related: [(10414)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10414/17).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the recursion algorithm fails to increase points near the Dirac points (actually, with a narrow band gap). It seems that it is because $\partial f(x,y)/\partial x,\ \partial f(x,y)/\partial y \ll 1$. However you can scale your function, scale back with a post-processing and obtain a nice plot!

```
scale = 1000;
postProcess[g_] := 
  g /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, opts___] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[(pts\[Transpose]/{1, 1, scale})\[Transpose], 
      opts] /. (VertexNormals -> 
      n_) :> (VertexNormals -> (n\[Transpose] {1, 1, 
          scale})\[Transpose]);
Timing[With[{plotopts = {Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
     Ticks -> {{-Pi, 0, Pi}, {-Pi, 0, Pi}, Automatic}, 
     PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
     ViewPoint -> {1.43, -2.84, 1.13}, 
     ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}}},
  plot1 = 
   Plot3D[(wp[qx, qy, r][[1]]) scale, {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, 
     plotopts] // postProcess;
  plot2 = 
   Plot3D[(wp[qx, qy, r][[2]]) scale, {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, 
     plotopts] // postProcess;]]
plot = Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> {0.96, 1.04}, 
  Ticks -> {{-Pi, 0, Pi}, {-Pi, 0, Pi}}, LabelStyle -> Medium, 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 3}, BoxStyle -> Opacity[0.4]]
```

[image]

You can see a fine mesh near the Dirac points:

[image]

Now you can obtain a considerable speedup by tuning `PlotPloits` and `MaxRecursion`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the plotting may be slow because you're trying to resolve a small feature and upping the number of points you use in the entire plot.

If you instead try upping the number of points only in the region between 0.99 and 1.01, where you know the sharp features are, you cut down on the amount of time spent searching:

```
Timing[With[{plotopts = {Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
     Ticks -> {{-Pi, 0, Pi}, {-Pi, 0, Pi}, Automatic}, 
     ViewPoint -> {1.43, -2.84, 1.13}, 
     ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}}},
  plot1 = 
   Plot3D[wp[qx, qy, r][[1]], {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, plotopts, 
    PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {-π, π}, {1.00, 1.01}}, 
    PlotPoints -> 40, ClippingStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];
  plot2 = 
   Plot3D[wp[qx, qy, r][[2]], {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, plotopts, 
    PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {-π, π}, {0.99, 1.00}}, 
    PlotPoints -> 40, ClippingStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];
  plot3 = 
   Plot3D[wp[qx, qy, r][[1]], {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, plotopts, 
    PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {-π, π}, {1.01, 1.04}}, 
    PlotPoints -> 20, ClippingStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];
  plot4 = 
   Plot3D[wp[qx, qy, r][[2]], {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, plotopts, 
    PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {-π, π}, {0.96, 0.99}}, 
    PlotPoints -> 20, ClippingStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];
  plot = Show[{plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}, PlotRange -> {0.96, 1.04},
     Ticks -> {{-Pi, 0, Pi}, {-Pi, 0, Pi}}, LabelStyle -> Medium, 
    BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 3}, BoxStyle -> Opacity[0.4]]

  ]
 ]
```

When I run this it looks the same as the plot you've posted but only takes about 4 seconds to plot.[image]

Answer (score 2):

One can use FEM's `ToElementMesh`, `MeshRefinementFunction`, and `ElementMeshPlot3D` to refine the plot.  `ElementMeshPlot3D` does not work like `Plot3D`. In particular `VertexNormals` are not computed, so I borrowed the utility function `addnormals[]` from [How to improve this plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129426/how-to-improve-this-plot/129453#129453) Also there is no `PlotStyle` option, so some other method needs to be used; it does have a `ColorFunction` option.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
emesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}},
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     Abs[Mean[wp[##, r][[1]] & @@@ vertices] - wp[##, r][[1]] & @@ 
        Mean[vertices]] > 0.0001]
   ];
Show[emesh["Wireframe"], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ClearAll[plotwp];

plotwp[wpr_, opts : OptionsPattern[ElementMeshPlot3D]] := 
 Module[{mins, wp1C, wp2C, vals1, eIF1, vals2, eIF2, emesh},
  wp1C = Compile[{qx, qy}, Evaluate[wpr[qx, qy][[1]] /. Sqrt[s_] :> Sqrt@Abs[s]]];
  wp2C = Compile[{qx, qy}, Evaluate[wpr[qx, qy][[2]] /. Sqrt[s_] :> Sqrt@Abs[s]]]; 
  emesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}},
    MeshRefinementFunction -> 
     Function[{vertices, area}, 
      Abs[Mean[wp1C @@@ vertices] - wp1C @@ Mean[vertices]] > 0.0001]
    ];
  vals1 = wp1C @@@ emesh["Coordinates"];
  eIF1 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, vals1];
  vals2 = wp2C @@@ emesh["Coordinates"];
  eIF2 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, vals2];
  Show[
   addnormals[eIF1][ElementMeshPlot3D[eIF1, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, opts]], 
   addnormals[eIF2][ElementMeshPlot3D[eIF2, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, opts]],
   PlotRange -> All, Options[plot]]
  ]


pl = plotwp[wp[##, r] &, ColorFunction -> None]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
pl = DeleteCases[pl, HoldPattern[VertexColors -> _], Infinity] /. 
 GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, r___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[
   p, {First@Charting`getPlotStyles[
       "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
          Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[$PlotTheme, Plot3D])][1, Opacity[0.7]],
    g}, r]
(* 0.529355  <-- timing  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Utility:

```
(*add VertexNormals to plot assumed to be the plot of the function u*)
addnormals[u_][plot_Graphics3D /; ! FreeQ[plot, GraphicsComplex]] := 
 plot /. GraphicsComplex[p_, rest___] :> 
   GraphicsComplex[p, rest, 
    VertexNormals -> 
     With[{dx = Derivative[1, 0][u], dy = Derivative[0, 1][u], 
       xy = p[[All, {1, 2}]]}, 
      Transpose@{-dx @@@ xy, -dy @@@ xy, ConstantArray[1., Length@p]}]
    ]
```