# How to improve this plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, regions

In general, the quality of Mathematica graphics is beyond praise.
However,  the  output of Plot3D command is somewhat unexpected in the following code. Let's solve the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation.

```
NDSolve[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 
Boole[y >= 0], True]}, u, {x,y} ∈ Disk[]];Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. %], 
{x, y} ∈ Disk[],PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

One sees the superfluous two peaks about (-1,0) and (1,0): it is well known that $u[x,y] \ge 0 $ and 
$u[x,y] \le 1$. Also the exact solution through the Poisson integral formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel confirms it.

What causes these peaks? How to get rid of the ones?

Comment: The problem is that `NDSolve` returns an `InterpolatingFunction`, which will not be the exact solution to your PDE.

Comment: @ kevin : Thank you. The question is still open and the problem seems to be serious.

Comment: With a strong exposition and a relatable protagonist :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suspect the problem arises from too coarse a mesh when the `Disk` region is discretized. A better result is obtained if the region is created explicitly with a finer mesh at the edge.

```
region = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.005 (1 - Norm[Mean[vertices]]^2)]]
```

[image]

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Boole[y >= 0], True]},
  u, {x, y} ∈ region]

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ region, PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Simon Woods : Thank you for your constructive answer which solves the problem. Is your region the unit disk? If it is not, your answer is a fake.

Comment: @user64494 It's obviously the unit disk.  Look up `Disk[]`, which you used in your answer.

Comment: @user64494, it's an approximation to the unit disk of course, because it's a mesh of triangles. The same applies when you use `Disk[]` as the region, but in that case the approximation is worse.

Comment: @ Michael E2 : Looking in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html , I am not sure about that.

Comment: @user64494, thank you, but there is no need to be so hasty with accepting an answer! You may get more and better answers if you leave the question "open" for a while. We usually suggest at least 24 hours so that users in all time zones have a chance to see it.

Comment: @user64494 `NDSolve` discretizes `Disk[]` using the same underlying algorithm, but with automatically chosen parameters. What Simon did was alter a parameter to give a finer mesh near the boundary. The discretization in Simon's code is more accurate than the automatic discretization used in yours. Neither, strictly speaking, is exactly the unit disk.

Answer (score 25):

### Interpolation error

The overshoots are the unavoidable result of interpolation. `NDSolve` computes the  values of `u` of the `DirichletCondition` to machine-precision accuracy and approximates the values of `u` at other points in the mesh via the finite element method.  Values at intermediate points are interpolated by polynomials that equal the values of `u` at the mesh points and approximate the derivatives of `u` at those points.  Consequently, there will be some error.  Perhaps surprisingly, the maximum error is about `1/8` in both the OP's and [Simon Woods'](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) solutions.

When `u[x, y]` is smooth, the error should be small. In the OP's case, there is a discontinuity, and approximating a discontinuity with a polynomial has limitations, reminiscent of [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) for trigonometric polynomials (Fourier series). *Mathematica* has [built-in methods for dealing with interpolation of discontinuities in 1D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/interpolating-data-with-a-step/98349#98349), but as far as I know, not for 2D or higher.

Here is a 1D illustration of the phenomenon, that is similar to what happens in **any** numerical solution of the OP's PDE produced by `NDSolve[]`. We interpolate the `UnitStep[]` function. Using `Plot[]` will result in interpolating the function between interpolation nodes. However `ListLinePlot[]` uses just the nodes.  We can see the overshoot in the `Plot[]` output.

```
ifn = Interpolation[Transpose@{#, UnitStep[# - 1/4]} &@Range[-1., 1., 1/2^4]];
GraphicsRow@{Plot[ifn[x], {x, -1, 1}], ListLinePlot@ifn}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Moreover, the overshoot does not go away or diminish in magnitude as the mesh is refined. All that happens is the width of the overshoot gets smaller:

```
Plot[Evaluate@ Table[Interpolation[
     Transpose@{#, UnitStep[# - 1/4]} &@Range[-1., 1., 1/2^n]][x], {n, 3, 6}],
   {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At some point, the bump can be so narrow that `Plot[]` misses it (unless you increase `PlotPoints` accordingly):

```
GraphicsRow@{
  Plot[Evaluate@ Interpolation[
      Transpose@{#, UnitStep[# - 1/4]} &@Range[-1., 1., 1./2^14]][x],
    {x, -1, 1}],
  Plot[Evaluate@ Interpolation[
      Transpose@{#, UnitStep[# - 1/4]} &@Range[-1., 1., 1./2^14]][x],
    {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 512]
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are other ways to control the overshoot in the 1D case, but I think those options do not exist for higher dimension, finite-element solutions.

### Discussion: addressing the error

At this point the question might be divided in two: Is the concern with the values of `u` computed by `NDSolve[]`, or with the interpolation error?

If the latter, the interpolation error can be constrained to a small region by a finer mesh around the discontinuities, as [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) shows.  The error is still there (about `1/8` in magnitude), but `Plot3D[]`, which produces a graphical approximation to the numerical approximation, misses it.  Thus the plot looks good.  This confines the error to a smaller area and can be considered a significant improvement.

If the former, there is a way to visualize the solution values, similar to `ListLinePlot[]` in the 1D case.  The FEM function `` NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshPlot3D `` plots a 2D `ElementMesh` interpolating function.  In the code for the graphics just below, `solOP` and `solSW` represent the `InterpolatingFunction` solutions from the OP and Simon Woods respectively. (Full code is given further down.)  The function `addnormals[u]` adds the [`VertexNormals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexNormals.html) to the surface defined by `z == u[x, y]`.
We can see that there is no overshoot in the plots of the computed values of `u[x, y]` of either solution.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

With[{plot = Show[ElementMeshPlot3D[solOP], Axes -> True]},
 GraphicsRow[{plot, addnormals[solOP]@plot}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
With[{plot = Show[ElementMeshPlot3D[solSW], Axes -> True]},
 GraphicsRow[{plot, addnormals[solSW]@plot}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code for `addnormals[]`:

```
(* add  VertexNormals  to  plot  assumed to be the plot of the function  u  *)
addnormals[u_][plot_Graphics3D /; ! FreeQ[plot, GraphicsComplex]] := 
 plot /. GraphicsComplex[p_, rest___] :> GraphicsComplex[
    p, rest, 
    VertexNormals -> 
     With[{dx = Derivative[1, 0][u], dy = Derivative[0, 1][u], xy = p[[All, {1, 2}]]},
      Transpose@{-dx @@@ xy, -dy @@@ xy, ConstantArray[1., Length@p]}]
    ]
```

### Further analysis of the interpolation error

We made some claims about the error above, for which we can give some evidence now.

First the code for the solutions: Simon Woods' refinement function may be passed to the underlying mesher via the `Method` option of `NDSolve` as shown below. It produces a slightly different mesh; but the mesh has similar properties to Simon's `region` and has virtually the same numerical properties shown below for `solSW`.  I think this method should be preferred, since the FEM algorithms are designed for solving PDEs.

```
solOP = u /. First@NDSolve[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Boole[y >= 0], True]}, 
     u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]];
solSW = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Boole[y >= 0], True]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ region, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {MeshRefinementFunction -> 
        Function[{vertices, area}, area > 0.005 (1 - Norm[Mean[vertices]]^2)]}}];
```

We can see that the range of computed values of `u` are within the theoretical range:

```
MinMax[solOP["ValuesOnGrid"]]
MinMax[solSW["ValuesOnGrid"]]
(*  {0., 1.}  *)
(*  {0., 1.}  *)
```

Next let's check the boundary for interpolation error. We get the mesh nodes and evaluate the solution at the midpoints between them.  This leads to an estimate of the error.  Note that its magnitude is about the same as the `UnitStep` function above, around `1/8` in magnitude in both the OP's and Simon's solutions.

```
coordsOP = SortBy[ArcTan @@ # &]@               (* sort into path order *)
   MeshCoordinates@ RegionBoundary@ MeshRegion[solOP["ElementMesh"]];
midpointsOP = Mean /@ Partition[coordsOP, 2, 1];
valuesOP = solOP @@@ midpointsOP;
MinMax[valuesOP] - {0, 1}
(*  {-0.124918, 0.124918}  *)

coordsSW = SortBy[ArcTan @@ # &]@               (* sort into path order *)
   MeshCoordinates@ RegionBoundary@ MeshRegion[solSW["ElementMesh"]];
midpointsSW = Mean /@ Partition[coordsSW, 2, 1, 1];
valuesSW = solSW @@@ midpointsSW;
MinMax[valuesSW] - {0, 1}
(*  {-0.124871, 0.124888}  *)
```

Comment: @ Michael E2: Many Mathematica users derive benefit and pleasure from your excellent answer. I'd like to notice that is known as the Gibbs phenomenon ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

Comment: @user64494 Thanks, for the compliment and for pointing out the typo.

Comment: +1 This is a really good answer. I must admit I hadn't realised that the magnitude of the interpolation error was constant as the mesh is refined.

Comment: Great answer!  And (slightly belated) congratulations on reaching 100k!  That represents a tremendous amount of your time spend on behalf of the community.  Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks, x2!