# Convergence Rate of NDSolve by Increasing the Spatial Grids

Tags: differential-equations, convergence

I have a very simple PDE equation, with an analytical solution (exact solution). And I want to play with NDSolve and increasing the number of Spatial Grids.

Here is the exact solution:(*Analytical Solution*)

```
cA[x_, t_] := Erf[x/(2 Sqrt[t])]
```

Here is how I use the NDSolve:

```
solveUniformGrid[nPoint_, order_, xMin_, xMax_, pGoal_] := 
 Block[{xgrid, sol},
  xgrid = Join[Range[xMin, xMax, xMax/(nPoint - 1)], {xMax}];
  sol = NDSolve[
    {
     D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x],
     u[xMax, t] == 1,
     u[x, tMin] == If[x == xMin, 0, 1],
     u[xMin, t] == 0
     }, u, {x, xMin, xMax}, {t, tMin, tMax},
    MaxSteps -> Infinity,
    InterpolationOrder -> Automatic,
    AccuracyGoal -> pGoal,
    PrecisionGoal -> pGoal,
    Method -> {
      "MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" ->
       {
        "TensorProductGrid", 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> order,
        "Coordinates" -> {xgrid}
        },
      "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> Automatic
      }];
  sol = First[u /. sol]
  ]
```

With `xMin = tMin = 0`, and `xMax = 10; tMax = 1;`

And then I calculate the Relative Error between the Analytical, and the Numerical solution: (The average of relative error in the domain of u[x,t]

```
calulateError[analytical_, numerical_, xMin_, xMax_, tMin_, tMax_, 
  nx_, nt_] :=
 Block[{xgrid, tgrid, errorList, percenterror},
  xgrid = Join[Range[xMin, xMax, xMax/(nx - 1)], {xMax}];
  tgrid = Join[Range[tMin, tMax, tMax/(nt - 1)], {tMax}];
  errorList = 
   Quiet[Abs[analytical[xgrid, #] - numerical[xgrid, #]]/
       analytical[xgrid, #] & /@ tgrid];
  errorList = 
   errorList /. {ComplexInfinity -> 0., Indeterminate -> 0.};
  percenterror = Mean[Flatten@errorList]
  ]
```

Now, I will play with the Grid Refinement, I will increase the number of spatial grid.

```
nPointList = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200};
solList1 = solveUniformGrid[#, 4, xMin, xMax, 8] & /@ nPointList;
```

And I plot the spatial error as a function of the number of grid points.

```
errorConcList1 = 
  calulateError[cA, #, xMin, xMax, tMin, tMax, 100, 50] & /@ solList1;

ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{nPointList, errorConcList1}], 
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, when I check the Convergence Rate, there is something I didn't understand.
when I increase the number of grids, the Relative Error is stuck at a level. (The relative error is only 0.01).

[image]

In general, when we increase the grid points, the relative error will decrease further. Can someone explain this? Thank you

**Update 01**

It is the way to calculate the Relative Error between the analytical, and the numerical function that I didn't do it well. With the help of Henrik, by using the **L2-Norm**, I've got the **correct convergence rate**.

[image]

**Update 02 - Improvement and Question about L2-Norm**
As you can see, the `cA` (analytical solution) is which is undefined at `t == 0`. So @Michael E2 has a very nice solution to compile and add the `If`condition here.

Here is the **3 analytical solutions:**, `cA` is the original analytical solution, `cACompile` is the compiled version by Michael E2, and `cAImprove` is just the non-compiled solution with an If condition to avoid the underfined problem at t==0.

```
cA[x_, t_] := Erf[x/(2 Sqrt[t])]

cACompile = Compile[{{xt, _Real, 1}},(*call:cA[{x,t}]*)
   Module[{x = First[xt], t = Last[xt]},
    If[x == 0,
     0.,
     If[t == 0,
      1.,
      Erf[x/(2 Sqrt[t])]
      ]]],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];

cAImprove[x_, t_] := If[x == 0,
  0.,
  If[t == 0,
   1.,
   Erf[x/(2 Sqrt[t])]
   ]]
```

**I made a performance test on 1000 000 grid points**

```
Thread[cA[Range[xMin, xMax, 0.00001], 0.5]]; // Timing
Thread[cAImprove[Range[xMin, xMax, 0.00001], 0.5]]; // Timing
cACompile /@ Thread[List[Range[xMin, xMax, 0.00001], 0.5]]; // Timing
```

And I get:

```
{0.03125, Null}

{0., Null}

{0.6875, Null}
```

### My 1st question is:

Why the `cAImprove` with an If injected is faster than the original `cA`? It should be slower, right?

### My 2nd question is:

How to obtain an L2-Norm between the two functions (exact, and approximation) for **all of the domaine {xgrid,tgrid}**?

Here is the 3 definitions of L2-Norm so far:

```
(* Integrate of L2-Norm on domain by Henrik Schumacher - Rather SLOW *)
globalIntegrateL2[anal_, num_] := 
 Divide[Sqrt[
   NIntegrate[
    Abs[anal[x, t] - num[x, t]]^2, {x, xMin, xMax}, {t, tMin, tMax}]],
   Sqrt[NIntegrate[
    Abs[anal[x, t]]^2, {x, xMin, xMax}, {t, tMin, tMax}]]]

(* L2 Norm on Grid by Michael E2 *)
traprule[yy_, xx_] := 
  Fold[#2.MovingAverage[#, 2] &, yy, Differences /@ xx];
globalGridL2[anal_, num_] := With[
  {
   xt = num@"Coordinates",
   exact = Apply[anal, num@"Grid", {2}],(*exact values on grid*)
   approx = num@"ValuesOnGrid"
   },(*computed solution on grid*)
  Divide @@ {traprule[(approx - exact)^2, xt] // Sqrt, 
    traprule[exact^2, xt] // Sqrt}]

(* L2 Norm on Grid by myself *)
globalGridL2Own[anal_, num_] := With[
  {
   exact = Apply[anal, num@"Grid", {2}],(*exact values on grid*)
   approx = num@"ValuesOnGrid"
   },
  Divide[Norm[approx - exact, 2], Norm[exact, 2]]
  ]
```

Here is the **convergence rate** of the 3 error functions. I don't know which one is correct.

[image]

Comment: You're missing values for the parameters `xMin`, `xMax`, `tMin`, `tMax`, which prevents people from understanding your problem or giving concrete advice.

Comment: I've added in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish to add two things, separating the error of the discrete solution computed by `NDSolve` from the interpolating error between the interpolation grid, and speeding up the computation of the norm.  The interpolation error is noticeable, but not significant in the $L^2$ norm, although it is probably the explanation of the OP's original difficulty with the point-wise-relative 1-norm.

One of the problems with speed is `cA`, which is undefined at `t == 0`.  A different definition, especially with `Compile` speeds up computation.

```
ClearAll[cA];
cA = Compile[{{xt, _Real, 1}}, (* call: cA[{x, t}] *)
   Module[{x = First[xt], t = Last[xt]},
    If[x == 0,
     0.,
     If[t == 0,
      1.,
      Erf[x/(2 Sqrt[t])]
      ]]],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

Some parameters. I memoized the solutions so I could play with them without recomputing them.  It's unneeded but some of the rest of the code assumes calling `sol[nx]` won't be slow.

```
pGoal = 8;
xMin = tMin = 0;
xMax = 10;
tMax = 1;
order = 4;

nxList = {25, 100, 400, 1600, 6400, 25600}; (* discretization sequence *)

ClearAll[sol];
mem : sol[nx_] := With[{xgrid = Subdivide[N@xMin, xMax, nx]},
   mem = NDSolveValue[
     {D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x],
      u[xMax, t] == 1, u[x, tMin] == If[x == xMin, 0, 1], 
      u[xMin, t] == 0},
     u, {x, xMin, xMax}, {t, tMin, tMax},
     MaxSteps -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> Automatic, 
     PrecisionGoal -> pGoal,
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> order, "Coordinates" -> {xgrid}}, 
       "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> Automatic}]
   ];

Do[sol[nx], {nx, nxList}] (* optional: pre-compute & memoize solutions *)
```

We compute the integral for the $L^2$ norm from the solution grid used by `NDSolve`.  The values we need, except for `"Grid"`, are stored in the solution and can be obtained from the `InterpolatingFunction`; the `"Grid"` is computed efficiently from the `"Coordinates"`.  The value of the `"Coordinates"` has the form `xx = {{x0, x1,..., xj}, {t0, t1,..., tk}}`, that is, a list of the x-grid and t-grid.

```
traprule[yy_, xx_] := 
  Fold[#2.MovingAverage[#, 2] &, yy, Differences /@ xx];

Table[With[{
   xt = sol[nx]@"Coordinates",
   exact = cA@ sol[nx]@"Grid",        (* exact values on grid *)
   approx = sol[nx]@"ValuesOnGrid"},  (* computed solution on grid *)
  Divide @@ {
    traprule[(approx - exact)^2, xt] // Sqrt,
    traprule[exact^2, xt] // Sqrt
    }
  ],
 {nx, {25, 100, 400, 1600, 6400, 25600}}]
ListLogPlot[%, Joined -> True]

(*  {0.00202437, 0.000244795, 0.0000493161, 0.0000394941, 0.000039159, 0.0000393847}  *)
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful idea of the Compiled function of cA. I really love it. I made a test between the cA, and the cACompile function. `Thread[cA[Range[xMin, xMax, 0.00001], 0.5]]; // Timing` and fhis, `cACompile /@ Thread[List[Range[xMin, xMax, 0.00001], 0.5]]; // Timing`. And I get `{0.03125, Null}` for the cA, and `{0.703125, Null}` for the Compiled version. So why the compiled version is slower? Thank you very much.

Comment: @NamNguyen The issue with the original problem is at `t == 0`.  It prevents the computation for `errorList` to be done as a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/4999). The compiled function gets around that with using `If`, and `If` is much faster inside `Compile` than in general. OTOH, if you avoid `t == 0` as in your comment, Mma uses the [vectorized `Erf[]`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-c/top/vector-mathematical-functions/vm-mathematical-functions/special-functions/v-erf.html)...

Comment: Vectorized functions in the MKL will generally be faster on arrays (on Intel machines, at least) than anything else. Note that the call to `cA` in `Thread[cA[Range[xMin, xMax, 0.00001], 0.5]]` results in a vectorized call to the arithmetic functions as well as `Erf[]`.  `Range` produces a packed array. And the `Thread` does nothing in this case. -- In your second, compiled example in the comment, there are three things I think slow things down. First is `Thread`, which does a somewhat expensive memory operation. Second are the two `If` tests in `caCompiled`. Third is that it's not vectorized.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've another question on L2-norm. Please read the updated question.

Answer (score 6):

For a parabolic PDE as yours, the a priori error estimates are typically of the form $\mathrm{error} \sim (h^k + \tau^{k/2})$ for some $k \geq 0$ that depends on both the method and the norm in which you measure the error. Here $\tau >0$ is the time step size (i.e. total time divided by number of spatial grids) and $h>0$ is the maximal cell size in the spatial grid. The error goes to $0$ only if *both* $h \to 0$ and $\tau \to 0$, but you let go only $h \to 0$ while you keep the choice of $\tau$ to `NDSolve` by using `MaxSteps -> Automatic`. It it might not converge to $0$.

**Edit:**

After a some redious reverse engineering, I do not understand what the problem is. I get a nicely decaying sequence of relative $L^2$-errors from the following:

```
cA[x_, t_] := Erf[x/(2 Sqrt[t])]
pGoal = 8;
xMin = tMin = 0;
xMax = 10;
tMax = 1;
order = 4;

Table[
 xgrid = Subdivide[N@xMin, xMax, nx];
 sol = NDSolveValue[{
    D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x],
    u[xMax, t] == 1,
    u[x, tMin] == If[x == xMin, 0, 1],
    u[xMin, t] == 0
    },
   u,
   {x, xMin, xMax}, {t, tMin, tMax},
   MaxSteps -> Automatic,
   InterpolationOrder -> Automatic,
   PrecisionGoal -> pGoal,
   Method -> {
     "MethodOfLines",
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> order, "Coordinates" -> {xgrid}},
     "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> Automatic}
   ];
 Divide[
  Sqrt[NIntegrate[Abs[sol[x, t] - cA[x, t]]^2, {x, xMin, xMax}, {t, tMin, tMax}]],
  Sqrt[NIntegrate[Abs[cA[x, t]]^2, {x, xMin, xMax}, {t, tMin, tMax}]]
  ],
 {nx, {100, 200, 400, 800}}]
```

> {0.000645067, 0.000229846, 0.0000890372, 0.0000484648}

Comment: I'm increasing the number of the spatial grid, so the cell size h->0, right?. The temporal t grid is controlled by ODA (adaptive) based on the Accuracy Goal. So my question is, how to make the error go to zero. So as your opinion, I will try to decrease the temporal step size too, is it right?

Comment: So then, do you refine the time grid, too? After all, you use `MaxSteps -> Automatic` and and fixed values for `AccuracyGoal ` and `PrecisionGoal `. That looks like "no".

Comment: I will update the question, by refining both space-grid, and time-grid.

Comment: Oh, and I see that you compute the relative error pointwise as $||(u - v)/v||_{L^1}$. So there is probaly also quite some catastrophic cancellation going on... Better try to use something like $||u - v||/||u||$ with some suitable norm (e.g., the $L^2$-norm).

Comment: could you please answer the question with a correct relative error function?

Comment: @NamNguyen I feel that the discontinuity in the boundary condition, `u[x, tMin] == If[x == xMin, 0, 1]`, probably limits the convergence, but I'm not very familiar with PDEs. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129426/how-to-improve-this-plot

Comment: @MichaelE2, yes, I know. That's why I want to play with the Mesh Refinement. When I increase the mesh number, the Relative Error will reduce, to a certain level, something like 10^-8. It should happen only with a very large number of mesh. But the plot shows that it converges with only 100 grid points. So strange for me.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I've tried to increase the t-grid, and use the L2-Norm, but I get the similar convergence rate. Can you post your own answer. It converges too soon, with about 100 grid points. Due to the singularity, it should converge with a lot of spatial grid points. That means when I increase the grid points (like 20 000 points), the relative error should go smaller. But no, in my case, it is constant. So strange. No difference between 500 grid points and 20 000 grid points.

Comment: Thank you @HenrikSchumacher. It was the way to calculate the relative error, that I didn't do it well. The correct way is using the L2-error. You are using NIntergrate, and it was so slow. I don't know the better way to do that. Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. `NIntegrate` takes probably so long because the analytical solution is discontinuous. Maybe the use of the option `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"` speeds it up a bit.