# Increasing Plot3D speed when plotted function is Eigenvalue

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, eigenvalues

This is probably a really simple fix, but I'm fairly new to Mathematica and am not sure how to do this properly. I know that trying to plot eigenvalues directly can be computationally expensive, so I'm trying to create a variable that makes a thread which allows me to plot things more quickly. I've been successful in doing so for a single variable in the following way

```
data[W_, q_, {xmin_, xmax_, dx_}] := Thread[Table[
({x, #} &)  /@ Sort[ Eigenvalues[Energies[x, q, W]] ],
{x, xmin, xmax, dx}]];
```

but am not sure how I'd do it when I want to plot over an x and y component so that it is 3 dimensional. What sort of syntax would one use for this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean `ListPlot3D`? It seems like you are making a table of the eigenvalues rather than plotting continuous functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

It might be worthwhile just specifying `PlotPoints`. For instance, if we use

```
Energies[_, _, x_, y_] := SparseArray[
  {Band[{1, 2}] -> Cos[x] Sin[y], Band[{2, 1}] -> Cos[x] Sin[y]}
  , {3, 3}]
```

as our set of test-matrices, then

```
Plot3D[Evaluate @ Sort @ Eigenvalues @ Energies[W, q, x, y]
  , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}
  , PlotPoints -> 10]
```

yields (much faster than generating the set of points, I might add):

[image]

**Original post**

Here's one way to go about this that directly generalizes your code.

```
data[W_, q_, {xmin_, xmax_, dx_}, {ymin_, ymax_, dy_}] := Transpose[
  Flatten[
   Table[
    {x, y, #} & /@ Sort[Eigenvalues[Energies[W, q, x, y]]]
    , {x, xmin, xmax, dx}
    , {y, ymin, ymax, dy}]
   , {1, 2}]
  , {2, 1}]
```

The `Flatten` is necessary in order to change the 2D list of one "sheet" of eigenvalues into a 1D list over all choices of `x` and `y`, and the `Transpose` is necessary in order to make the output a list of the different "sheets" of eigenvalues. (By the way, if I've interpreted things correctly, you could have replaced `Thread` with `Transpose` in your code, although there doesn't seem to be any speed gain.)

To test this, we define 3 by 3 test matrices:

```
Energies[_, _, x_, y_] := RandomReal[{-x, y}, {3, 3}]
```

and call the function as

```
data1[W, q, {0, 1, 0.05}, {-3, 3, 0.1}]
```

This is the proper format for `ListPlot3D`, so if we call

```
ListPlot3D[ data1[W, q, {0, 1, 0.05}, {-3, 3, 0.1}] ]
```

we get, for example, the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! One followup question though. If my eigenvalues are actually continuous functions in x and y, is there a way to make this work with Plot3D? To get the plots looking like they did with Plot3D, I need to make dx and dy in the order of .005 and this sacrifices a lot of the speed gain.

Comment: @ChrisThomas. You could start perhaps by specifying `PlotPoints`. My examples evaluate pretty fast. What is the size of your matrices and how complicated are the entries? The speed-up might happen there instead. (Also, see the updated answer.)

Comment: The matrices are 4x4 block-diagonal but the entries are somewhat complicated since they are complex exponential tight-binding parameters. The reason I needed a bit of a speedup is the fact that in order to see the points where the two sheets meet you need quite a large number of plot points (or else it looks like it's got a fairly sizable gap.) I will try the updated answer and see if it works better!

Comment: @ChrisThomas. If you need more resolution near certain points (or curves), [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/improve-plot3d-resolution-near-max-mins](this question and answer) and [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56236/plot-more-points-only-in-specific-region-of-plot?lq=1](this question and answer) might be helpful. Alternatively, you can use `ListPlot3D` and increase the resolution only near the special points.