# FunctionInterpolation with some datapoints to start with

Tags: interpolation, physics

**Motivation:**
I am using `FunctionInterpolation[COMSOL[x]]` in combination with COMSOL to search for the interpolation of my COMSOL model.

COMSOL needs a lot of time to calculate particular configuration (several minutes). Sometimes I need to stop the computation and would like to continue with it later. Is it possible to store and reuse the data computed in in previews step with `FunctionInterpolationp[]`?

**Basic example**
Here is basic example where I mimic COMSOL response with

```
COMSOL[t_] := Sin[t]
```

Let say I already have the data from previous calculation

```
dataOld = Table[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 π, π/10}]
```

Is there a way to include in `FunctionInterpolation[COMSOL[]]` the `dataOld`?

```
x1 = FunctionInterpolation[COMSOL[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

Comment: To clarify: You do have some domain (e.g., [0,20]) and then you have function values for input data, e.g., `oldData` are $\{ (x_1,f(x_1)), \ldots , (x_n, f(x_n))\}$. And now you want to enter new points from the same domain, to find an interpolating function for the union of these sets?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note `FunctionInterpolation`  does not deal with points but with functions. If you want to interpolate points, use `Interpolation`

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216/adaptive-sampling-for-slow-to-compute-functions-in-2d/ seems to be what i am looking for.

Comment: But that answer is mainly concerned with the question _where_ to sample new points. A different question, don’t you think? Maybe you can makes this question more clear, if it is still relevant.

Comment: The idea was to use FunctionInterpolation  to build the model based on output from COMSOL simulation. FunctionInterpolation should then take care of smart sampling. But it seems that the method can not include starting points (or points from previews calculation). I tested the code posted in link above. Adaptive sampling works nice and then I use FunctionInterpolation on data to get the model. Thanks for support.